# Git ignores deleted file on merge

Tags: git

I have two repositories. From time to time, I want to merge the content of `other` into `main`. However the merge ignores deleted files. Let me explain it through an example:

```
mkdir -p test/main test/other

cd test/other/
git init
touch one two three
git add .
git commit -m "Add one, two and three."

cd ../main/
git init
touch four
git add .
git commit -m "Add four."
```

Add `other` to `main` as remote.

```
git remote add other ../other/
git fetch other
```

Merge its content.

```
git merge --squash other/master
git commit -m "Merge other."
```

It adds the files correctly. Now, remove a file in `other`.

```
cd ../other/
git rm two
git commit -m "Remove two."
```

Merge changes into `main`.

```
cd ../main/
git fetch other
git merge --squash other/master
```

After the merge `git status` says:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I would expect the merge to delete `two`, as it was deleted in `other`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is your use of squash commits.

When you do a `merge --squash`, you abandon all of the history of a branch. You haven't really "merged the branch" - you've just applied a condensed representation of its history. So if you do a later `merge --squash`, git will reapply *all* the commits in the branch's history (since the two branches have no common ancestor).

When you perform the *first* `merge --squash`, you create a commit on `main` which contains "Create one, two, and three". So the history of `main` is first "create four", then "create one, two, and three".

When you do the second `merge --squash`, you add a commit which consists of (in effect) "Create one, two, and three" plus "Remove two". The net of those two commits **together** (squashed!) is "Create one and three". So git auto-merges the "Create one and three" commit with your current repo state - leaving you with four files present. The content merge succeeds automatically because the files "one" and "three" are identical on both sides.

You should use "real" merges or cherry-picking instead of squashing if you want to keep a repo up-to-date with a remote. A `merge --squash` is not the same thing as "play through all the new commits in a remote repository and integrate them here".

Comment: True, this explanation makes sense. I wanted to do a squash merge to not pollute the history of main with other. But looks like there is no other way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GergoErdosi If you want to *view* the "unpolluted" history, look at the `first-parent` option to `git log`.

Comment: @Borealid We just have to do `git merge` without `--squash` flag right?