# Merge conflicts ruin my commit message while squashing commits

Tags: git, merge

My usual workflow with git is to create a new feature branch, do some work with frequent commits, and then merge back into the development branch when the feature is working and/or stable.

Usually, when I do `git merge --squash feature-branch`, I get a nice "squashed commit of the following" message that auto-populates with all of the commit messages from the feature branch.

However, if there are any merge conflicts (say I finished and merged another feature while working on this one), I seem to lose all of my commit messages from the branch. The auto-populated commit message fills in the conflicts, but not the commit messages. Where did my commit messages go? Can I get them back?

Comment: Why squash at all? You could just use `rebase --interactive` to clean up, if you regard your commits as too frequent and messy, then do a normal merge - that way you don't lose history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you should be able to avoid the conflict in the first place.

Consider doing a

```
git rebase master topic
```

before performing the merge. The DESCTIPTION section of this page http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase should be helpful.This may also obviate the need for the squash as an interactive rebase would allow you to to squash commits of your choosing.

EDIT:
See also: [In git, what is the difference between merge --squash and rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase)

Comment: You definitely wouldn't need a squash merge at that point - it'd be a fast-forward.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can get the squash commit message back.  It's stored in .git/SQUASH_MSG.

You can use it as a template with the following command:

```
git commit -t .git/SQUASH_MSG
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me directly, but thanks for the pointer to `.git/SQUASH_MSG` :)

Comment: I ran the command `git commit --file .git/SQUASH_MSG` and it created the commit message listing all commits within the squashed commit.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is really lost with git. The list of the commits on the feature branch can be obtained using:

```
git cherry feature-branch
```

Then simply pipe this to `git cat-file`:

```
git cherry feature-branch | cut -f2 -d' ' | git cat-file --batch
```

You need to clean-up the output though.  I don't know a way to automated it better.