# Git rebase (Merge Squash) my feature branch onto another branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

I'm looking for a git command to help me with my feature branches when they're ready to go into Master. This git command would squash all my changes on my branch into a single commit on top of master. I do this today with:

```
git rebase origin/master
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Where 4 is the number of commits to squash. However, this requires me to know how many commits I have. I do this today by running:

```
git log HEAD...origin/master
```

and then counting the commits.

I feel as though there should be a better way to do this. Or is this how everyone else does it, too?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't this exactly what `git rebase -i origin/master && git checkout master && git merge <feature_branch>` does?

Comment: ... Provided you decide to squash during the interactive rebase that is.

Comment: For the specific objective of counting the commits between your feature branch and master, you can do `git log --oneline master..FEATURE-BRANCH | wc -l`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use git merge --squash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash)

Comment: @Abhijeet It is the same solution, but I didn't know about the squash command when I asked this question. Finding that other question requires me to know the answer.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature_branch
```

As the [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-merge) for `git merge --squash` say:

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit or move the HEAD, nor record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit. This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

After that, you can `git commit` your changes which are already staged.

Comment: this looks like it, though that's some pretty deep technical language in the docs. Is it basically saying that the branch you're merging from (feature_branch) remains unchanged? but that a subsequent merge would be really ugly?

Comment: @JohnHinnegan: yes, the merged branch remains unchanged.

Comment: nice. So, tangent question. If head of master is A. Then feturebranch has changes B and C. We do a merge --squash on master, so now it's A->BC. Then we add change D to the feature branch and try to squash again, does Master know that change BC is the same as changes B and C and will only add change D becoming A->BC->D?

Comment: @JohnHinnegan: why don't you try for yourself? branching and merging is no expensive stuff. set up a test repo and play.

Comment: Just for clarity, this will put your "squashed" changes in the staging area from which you make your actual commit to master

Answer (score 17):

Here is what I do, gathered from a lot of experience working in larger teams:

```
# Get latest from master
git checkout master
git pull --rebase

# rebase master into your feature branch
git checkout feature/my-feature
git rebase master --preserve-merges

# merge feature into master
git checkout master

# DO ONLY ONE of the 2 options below
# if you only have one or (maybe) 2 commits in your feature branch
git merge feature/my-feature

# OR
# this forces an empty merge commit (useful if we need to roll things back)
git merge --no-ff feature/my-feature

# if you use Github, this should also close the pull request
git push origin master
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `this forces an empty merge commit (useful if we need to roll things back)`

What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `git merge --squash`. It should bring in the commits from your feature branch into master and squashes them, so that you can create a single commit.