# GIT merge / rebase upstream without fetching the history (Laravel 4 )

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently building an app with Laravel 4 framework. The problem i have is that the APIs are changing basically everyday so every time I upgrade the framework ( composer update ) my app breaks.

The suggested worklfow that I have seen online ([here](http://niallobrien.me/2013/03/installing-and-updating-laravel-4/), [there](http://www.codycovey.com/laravel-4-installation-and-updates/)) is to add the Laravel 4 repo as a remote and then using GIT rebase/merge with the upstream whenever upgrading. Which does the trick to update the code but the side effect is that I now end up having the whole framework histoy in my Git tree, which with 3k+ commits is kind of ugly.

Would there be a better way to do so?

Is it possible to only pull the difference between a remote commit and my local head and apply them (as a patch maybe) so that the remote history do not follow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the git history when you merge from upstream (laravel) then have a look at `git merge --squash`.  It's been answered before at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051/1269513