# Git rebase - coalesce changes and apply them all together

Tags: git, rebase

I feel like there must be a simple answer for this...

I can get a coalesced diff of changes on a branch. `git diff somecommit..latestcommit`. Easy enough.

I can rebase a branch onto a different branch. `git rebase -i updatedbranch rebasedbranch`. Simple.

With interactive mode, I can even squash that down into one commit.

But I can't get both to happen at once. I can't get the coalesced diff to be used for the rebase. It wants to apply every commit, one by one. There's like 50 of them, and every time I'm going through `git mergetool` and making the same choices, 50 times in a row. The coalesced diff is something like 2500 lines. We're talking about a lot of work here. There must be an easier way.

**What I'm trying to do**: get the coalesced changes applied between two commits on one branch (like `git diff a..b`), and replay those changes on another branch.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

TIL: `git apply`. Seriously, git is a bottomless pit of functions.

For others:

```
git diff a..b > ab.diff
git checkout otherbranch
git apply ab.diff
```

Easy.

Comment: [Squash-merging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash) might be even slightly easier; especially for people who are affraid of patches and `git apply` ;)