# Git delete branch and all corresponding changes

Tags: git

I'm a newbie to git, and got a little ahead of myself in creating/deleting branches and wanted to figure out the right process. Basically, I started on a new branch (`branch_a`) and then made a few changes. I then decided to test a third party package knowing it may not work as I wanted. At this point, I have a few changes in branch A which I didn't stage or commit. I went on to checkout a new branch (`branch_b`). I played around with this "test branch" and then decided to delete it. First I did a check-out of the original branch:

```
git checkout branch_a
```

Then, I deleted the branch thinking all the changes I made would get deleted too:

```
git branch -d branch_b
```

So the branch gets deleted but when I go back to `branch_a` to continue work from where I left off, I see the changes I made in `branch_b` are still there. Since I didn't commit anything before, I can't figure out how to separate the changes pre-`branch_b` and post-`branch-b`. Is this still possible?

And in terms of "the process", is there a better way to create and delete test branches? E.g. should I have used `git reset --hard`?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't stash or commit your changes to `branch_a`? Usually git doesn't allow you to check out a branch while your working directory is dirty. If you really didn't stash or commit you're out of luck and will have to revert the `branch_b` changes by hand, git has no way of knowing what you want to keep.

Comment: Nah, didn't stash or commit any changes. The new checkout worked fine just giving me this message:
`M db/schema.rb`
`M log/development.log`
`Switched to a new branch 'branch_b'`
Looks like I should have used git stash!

Comment: Yes, or just commit. With git/distributed version control you generally want to commit often. You can always squash your commits/branch afterwards or organize everything neatly when merging back to master with [`git merge --squash branchname`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash)

Comment: @dtech git allows you to change branch even with dirty working tree, for example if the new branch point to the same commit as the old one.

Comment: @user2301903 Please add the output of `git branch -vv` to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to conjecture at what happened.

You made changes in `branch_a`.  You did not commit.  You checked out new branch `branch_b`, did some stuff, did not commit.  Now you switched back to `branch_a`.  git will indeed let you carry over a dirty working directory.

**To Clean It Up (assuming my conjecture is right)**

In order to clean up your mess, perform a `git status`.  You need to `git add` all the items you want to for `branch_a`.  Then perform a `git commit` to save what you want in `branch_a`.  Note that it only commits the items you added to the stage.

Now you're free to go back to `branch_b`, `git add` stuff you want there, and commit that, too.  `git status` has nice help text to help you along the way.

**My recommended workflow:**

You work on `branch_a`.  You get an idea to try something different.  If you think you'll be back to `branch_a` within 15 minutes, perform a `git stash save <message>`.  This keeps the `branch_a` stuff separate.  If you're going to be longer, just commit it.  Don't worry, you can clean it up later with an interactive rebase:  `git rebase -i`.  Stashes are a bit annoying to have hang around, and you can accidentally delete them or pop them when you don't mean to.

Now go back to `master`, and create `branch_b`.  My favorite way is the all-in-one command `git checkout -b branch_b`.  Now you can work there.  Once you're done experimenting, again either stash or commit.  Remember as long as you don't push, you can commit willy nilly and clean it up later with interactive rebasing.

Check out `branch_a` and continue working there.  If you had stashed something, pop the stash:  `git stash pop`.  Otherwise you committed, and it's already there waiting for you.

Comment: Yea, that's basically what I did but I also deleted `branch_b` thinking it would discard changes made in that branch. I fixed it by hand since it wasn't too convoluted. Next time, I'll utilize `git stash` and also commit more often (rather than after hitting a "milestone")

Answer (score 1):

Use `gitk --all` to see which branch currently points to which commit.

If you did not commit your changes, git does not know anything about your change.

Use `git status` to check if the files in your working tree differ from those known to git. It will also tell you how to change that.

Before changing branch make sure you either commit your changes (to let you current branch know about your changes) or discard you changes. Never change you branch with uncommitted changes.

It will also help to configure a good git prompt for your shell. For bash you can use something like:

```
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=yes # show changed files as `*`
GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=yes # show new files as `%`
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=yes 
GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=auto
```

If you set you prompt that way, just make sure it does not show `*` or `%` before changing branch. And if it does use `git status` for help what to do.

Comment: Cool, gitk is really useful!

Comment: +1 for the git prompt tips.  Is there a way to speed things up at all?? When I modified my bash prompt, it lags something fierce every time it needs to display the prompt.