# git branch cleanup with squash for a pull request

Tags: git, github

I would like to create a pull request for a branch (`uglyCommitsBranch`) that I have, but it has lots of commit messages I would like to squeeze into one commit.
To do so, I think the following steps need to happen:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git branch newFeature
git push origin newFeature
git checkout newFeature
```

Now I need to take stuff from `uglyCommitsBranch` and put them all into `newFeature`, then push to origin for code review.

What are the next commands I need to run?
I am not sure how to run rebase commands and am afraid of breaking `master`.

If I am currently on `newFeature` branch (clean branch off `master`), what are the next commands to get this done?

Comment: Note: I have amended my answer in light of the new workflow described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36377634/6309.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that:

Simply stay in `uglyCommitBranch` and do an [interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/#rebasing-commits-against-a-point-in-time): clean your commits there, and the force push that branch: your pull-request (if it existed before the rebase, a PR made from that branch) will update itself.
If there was no pull request yet, you still can `push --force` as long as nobody else was working on `uglyCommitBranch` (since it is your fork).

---

That being said, if you want to stay in `newFeature` branch, then:

```
git merge --squash uglyCommitBranch
```

(As described in "[How to use `git merge --squash`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051/6309)")

---

Or since March 2016, you can leave the "commit squashing" to the main repo maintainer.
See "[Github squash commits from web interface on pull request after review comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36377634/6309)".