# How should I use git to get a fast feedback cycle?

Tags: git

I use git to code on my desktop, test the changes, commit and push to the server. Everything was well until yesterday; I was debugging a subtle network issue with a project, and I had to get a fast feedback loop - seeing the output quickly to learn more about the problem, rince and repeat.
What I ended up doing is `git commit -am "trying to fix bug X" && git push` on my desktop, and `git pull`, compile and run on the server.
I know this isn't the right way to use it, so I'm wondering, **how should I have used git**? I couldn't test my changes (as in, send requests to the network) on my desktop, so I needed the server to execute the new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can:

- isolate all those intermediate commit on a `fix` branch
- push that `fix` branch as many time as needed
- pull from the `fix` branch on the server

Once the bug is fix, [squash the commits of `fix` on `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051/6309), and push `master`.
Reset the server repo on `origin/master`.

Comment: Ideally, you use a separate server for this (not your production server), and use a script/hook that automatically pulls from the fix branch whenever you push.