# Git : Merge multiple commits from one branch into another

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I have following use case.

1. I have a mainline branch.
2. Created new branch(dev) from **mainline**.
3. Did multiple commits(around 20) into **dev** branch and pushed into **dev**(remote) branch as well.

Now I want to merge all these 20 commits into single commit and move this to **mainline**. How exactly I can do this?

Thanks in Advance,
Shantanu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That sounds like a [`git merge --squash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051/6309)

```
git checkout mainline
git merge --squash dev
git commit
```

Note that, as [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25387972/6309), it is best to merge `mainline` in `dev` first and solve any conflict there, before merging back `dev` in `mainline`.