# How to use git when feature take long time to develop

Tags: git

Lets say I got a feature that takes me 3 days to complete.

After each day I'd to like backup my data somehow but not pushing commits to main branch since the feature is not complete.

If I do a new branch and commits three times to it and then merge it with main branch you are gonna have an ugly history:

```
WIP featureA
WIP featureA
Added feature A
```

Should I squash my three commit messages into one single before I merges? Like this: [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Is this the best approach?

Comment: That sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/a/34328663/6309

Comment: In 3 days if you have 20 commits in your branch and then merge to master, those 20 commits will appear in master. They don't need to look pretty, do they? I personally love to review the progression of a branch.

Answer (score 0):

yep. you can commit as many commits as you wish.

Once you done use the :

```
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Where X is the number of the commits that you want to combine together. This is called **interactive rebase** or `squash``

Once you squash your commits - choose the `s` for squash = it will combine all the commits into a single commit.

[image]