# I pushed gemfile and gemfile.lock to my branch, do I have to merge to master?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I did a git add, git commit, and git push for 9 files (2 of those being Gemfile and Gemfile.lock). My team has informed me that we do not need Gemfile and gemfile.lock in the code review. What is the easiest way to revert these 2 files? (I would like to keep the other 7). I pushed these changes to my branch, can I ignore them when I am merging to master? Or should I somehow revert the changes to the 2 files (Gemfile and gemfile.lock)?

Comment: How many commits on your branch?

Comment: Does `master` already contain versions of Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: @meagar Yes, it does.

Comment: Are your commits not dependant on the changes in the `Gemfile` (assuming you added gems?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing is to reset `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to their present state on `master`.

You can do this in two ways; either by adding a new commit which discards your changes to those files, or by amending whichever commit introduced those changes.

The former is the simplest. Add a new commit on your branch which discards the changes you made to `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`:

1. Check out your branch, in its current state, with Gemfile and Gemfile.lock
2. Check out `master`'s version of `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`:

   ```
   $ git checkout master -- Gemfile Gemfile.lock
   ```
3. Add and commit your changes

   ```
   $ git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock
   $ git commit -m "Discard changes to Gemfile and Gemfile.lock"
   ```

Now you can push, and the changes will disappear from your branch.

Note that this is the easier solution but that it leaves your branch in a *slightly* weird state, both introducing and removing changes to some files. Once you've done this, you can [squash your entire branch down to a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash) prior to merging, and all history of the needlessly introduced changes to `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` will be discarded.