# Git: Do commits on local, merged branch get pushed to remote?

Tags: git

Assume I have the following git history

```
          L1 - L2 - L3  <- Local branch
         /            \
A - B - C -- D -- E -- M <- master
```

where L1, L2, and L3 are commits on my local branch and M is the merge commit into master.

Now, when I push my changes to remote, will the commits in the local branch be part of the history or not? In other words, will the history in the remote repository look like the graph above or just like

```
A - B - C - D - E - M <- master
```

Also: What happens in the case of fast-forward merges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge commit has two parent commits. You cannot just cut out the commits of the local branch from the history. M cannot exist without L3, L3 cannot exist without L2, and so on. This integrity is a fundamental to Git. So the pushed `master` branch will necessarily "look like a graph", the commits on the local branch won't vanish into thin air.

In a fast-forward merge, nothing special happens. The history is linear. It's not really a merge, it's really "just fast-forward".
In your example, suppose there are no commits D and E, you merge the local branch, then the history becomes:

```
A - B - C - L1 - L2 - L3 <- master
```

Notice that there is no M either (no merge commit).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. And for the sake of completeness, if one wants to combine the whole branch into one commit, `git merge --squash` is the way to go, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051/4920424).