# How to make --squash default on a merge?

Tags: git, merge

We use separate branches for non-trivial bug fixes and features. The branchhes are kept in-sync with master by performing frequent `git checkout <x>; git merge master`.

I noticed when merging, git pollutes the log files with multiple, non-relevant messages. For example, rather than a single "Merge <X> into Master" or "Merge Master into <X>", git will add all the commit messages. Its a problem with governance (processes sand procedures) on Master because the bugs that may have been present in a branch during development are ***not*** and were ***not*** ever present in the Master branch.

Worse, the behaviors are different between branches and master. When merging master into branches, there is a log entry generated similar to "Merge Master into <X>". However, when merging a branch into Master, there is no "Merge <X> into Master". According to the logs, its as if the development branch never existed and the merge never occurred.

I learned I had to do something special to make git behave as expected; namely [How to use git merge --squash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5308816) (Its classic git *modus operandi*: take something simple and make it difficult).

My question is, how do I make `--squash` the default action during a merge?

Comment: http://build.pixelunion.net/automatically-squash-and-fixup-your-git-rebase/

Comment: Forgive my ignorance Bryce... Is `git config --global merge.squash true` all that's needed? The blog post does not discuss it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know. This looked like a cut and paste solution to the problem you are having, so I provided the link for you. I did not attempt to replicate it on my machine. Regardless, you should back up your data if you plan on doing anything you are unsure about in git.

Comment: Regarding your problem with "disappearing dev branches without a merge", use `git merge --no-ff` to always create a merge-commit, even if it could be resolved with a fast-forward merge.

Comment: @knittl - we [stopped using Git development branches](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/WvyI6Z63z1I/8xM9cAqRBAAJ). All of these problems are now solved. I cast the first close vote using the reason ***Problem can no longer be reproduced***.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make Git always do a squash "merge" for the `master` branch:

```
$ git config branch.master.mergeOptions "--squash"
```

### Explanation

You can't make Git do a squash "merge" by default for *all* branches, but you *can* make it do a squash "merge" by default for *some* branches.  Since you are particularly interested in making this happen only for `master`, that may be just what you want.

Let's do a quick<sup>1</sup> review of what `git merge` really does since, in the usual Git fashion, Git complicates everything.  And, this:

> We use separate branches for non-trivial bug fixes and features. The branches are kept in-sync with master by performing frequent `git checkout <x>; git merge master`.

is reversed from what many people believe to be the "correct" work-flow in Git.  I have some doubts as to whether any Git work-flow can be called "correct" :-) , but some are more successful than others, and this is definitely the reverse of one of the more successful ones.  (I do think it can work well, as noted in the extended discussion below.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, I *tried* to keep it short. :-)  Feel free to skim, although there's a bunch of important material here.  If TL;DR, just jump straight to the end.

#### The commit graph

As you know, but others may not, in Git, much is controlled by the commit graph.  Every<sup>1</sup> commit has some parent commit, or in the case of a merge commit, two or more parents.  To make a new commit, we get on some branch:

```
$ git checkout funkybranch
```

and do some work in the work-tree, `git add` some files, and finally `git commit` the result to branch `funkybranch`:

```
... work work work ...
$ git commit -m 'do a thing'
```

The *current* commit is the (one, single) commit to which the name `funkybranch` points.  Git finds this by reading `HEAD`: `HEAD` normally contains the name of the branch, and the branch contains the raw SHA-1 hash ID of the commit.

To make the new commit, Git reads the ID of the current commit from the branch we're on, saves the index/staging-area into the repository,<sup>2</sup> writes the new commit with the current commit's ID as the new commit's parent, and—last—writes the *new* commit's ID to the branch information file.

This is how a branch grows: from one commit, we make a new one, and then move the branch name to point to the new commit.  When we do this as a linear chain, we get a nice linear history:

```
... <- C <- D <- E   <-- funkybranch
```

Commit `E` (which might actually be `e35d9f...` or whatever) is the current commit.  It points back to `D` because `D` *was* the current commit when we made `E`; `D` points back to `C` because `C` was current at that point; and so on.

When we make *new branches* with, e.g., `git checkout -b`, all we are doing is telling Git to make a new *name*, pointing to some existing commit.  Usually this is just the current commit.  So if we are on `funkybranch` and `funkybranch` points to commit `E` and we run:

```
git checkout newbranch
```

then we get this:

```
... <- C <- D <- E   <-- funkybranch, newbranch
```

That is, both names point to commit `E`.  Git knows that we're on `newbranch` now because `HEAD` says `newbranch`.  I like to include that in this kind of drawing too:

```
... <- C <- D <- E   <-- funkybranch, HEAD -> newbranch
```

I also like to draw my graphs in a bit more compact fashion.  We know that commits always point "backwards in time" to their parents, because it's impossible to make new commit `E` before we've made commit `D`.  So these arrows always point leftward and we can just draw one or two dashes:

```
...--C--D--E   <-- funkybranch, HEAD -> newbranch
```

(and then if we don't need to know which commit is which, we can just draw a round `o` node for each one, but for now I will stick to single uppercase letters here).

If we make a new commit now—commit `F`—it causes `newbranch` to advance (because, as we can see from `HEAD`, we're on `newbranch`).  So let's draw that:

```
...--C--D--E      <-- funkybranch
            \
             F    <-- HEAD -> newbranch
```

Now let's `git checkout funkybranch` again, and do some work there and commit it, making new commit `G`:

```
...--C--D--E--G   <-- HEAD -> funkybranch
            \
             F    <-- newbranch
```

(and `HEAD` is now pointing to `funkybranch`).  Now we have something we can merge.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, every commit except for *root commits*.  In most Git repositories there is just one root commit, which is the very first commit.  Obviously it cannot have a parent commit, since the parent of each new commit is whatever commit was current when we made the new commit.  With no commits at all, there is no current commit yet when we make the first commit.  So it becomes a root commit, and then all *later* commits are its children, grandchildren, great-grand-children, and so on.

<sup>2</sup>Most of the "save" work actually happens at each `git add`.  The index/staging-area contains hash IDs, rather than actual file contents: the file contents were saved away when you ran `git add`.  This is because Git's graph is not just of commit objects, but of *every* object in the repository.  This is part of what makes Git so fast as compared to, e.g., Mercurial (which saves the files away at commit time rather than add time).  Fortunately this, unlike the commit graph itself, is something users need not know or care about.

#### Git merge

As before, we have to be on some branch.<sup>1</sup>  We're on `funkybranch`, so we are all good to go:

```
$ git merge newbranch
```

At this point, most people seem to think that Magic Happens.  It's not magic at all though.  Git now finds the *merge base* between our current commit and the one we named, and then runs two `git diff` commands.

The merge base is simply<sup>2</sup> the first commit "in common" on the two branches—the first commit that is on *both* branches.  We are on `funkybranch`, which points to `G`.  We gave Git the branch *name* `newbranch`, which points to commit `F`.  So we're merging commits `G` and `F`, and Git follows both of their parent pointers until it reaches a commit node that is on both branches.  In this case, that's commit `E`: commit `E` is the merge base.

Now Git runs those two `git diff` commands.  One compares the merge base against the current commit: `git diff <id-of-E> <id-of-G>`.  The second diff compares the merge base against the other commit: `git diff <id-of-E> <id-of-F>`.

Finally, Git attempts to combine the two sets of changes, writing the result to our current work-tree.  If the changes *seem* independent, Git takes both of them.  If they *seem* to collide, Git stops with a "merge conflict" and makes us clean it up.  If they seem to be the *same* changes, Git takes just one copy of the changes.

All of this "seems" stuff is done on a purely textual basis.  Git has no understanding of code.  It just sees things like "delete a line reading `++x;`" and "add a line reading `y *= 2;`.  Those look different, so as long as they seem to be in different areas, it does the one delete and the one add, to the files in the merge-base, putting the result in the work-tree.

Last, assuming all goes well and the merge does not stop with a conflict, Git makes a new commit.  The new commit is a *merge commit*, which means it has two<sup>3</sup> parents.  The *first* parent—the order matters—is the *current commit*, just as with regular, non-merge commits.  The *second* parent is the other commit.  Once the commit is safely written to the repository, Git writes the new commit's ID into the branch name, as usual.  So, assuming the merge works, we get this:

```
...--C--D--E--G--H  <-- HEAD -> funkybranch
            \   /
              F     <-- newbranch
```

Note that `newbranch` has not moved: it still points to commit `F`.  `HEAD` has not changed either: it still contains the name `funkybranch`.  Only `funkybranch` has changed: it now points to the new merge commit `H`, and `H` points back to `G`, and also to `F`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git is a bit schizoid about this.  If we `git checkout` a raw SHA-1, or anything else that is not a branch *name*, it goes into a state it calls "detached HEAD".  Internally, this works by shoving the SHA-1 hash directly into the `HEAD` file, so that `HEAD` gives the commit ID, rather than the name of the branch.  But the way Git does everything else makes it work as though we're on a special branch whose name is just the empty string.  It's the (single) anonymous branch—or, equivalently, it's the branch named `HEAD`.  So in one sense, we're *always* on a branch: even if Git says that we're not on any branch, Git also says that we're on the special anonymous branch.

This causes a lot of confusion, and it might be more sensible if it weren't allowed, but Git uses it internally during `git rebase`, so it's actually pretty important.  If the rebase goes wrong, this detail leaks out, and you wind up having to know what "detached HEAD" means, and is.

<sup>2</sup>I am deliberately ignoring a hard case here, which occurs when there are multiple possible merge base commits.  Mercurial and Git use different solutions here: Mercurial picks one at (what seems to be) random, while Git gives you options.  These cases are rare though, and ideally, even when they do occur, Mercurial's simpler method works anyway.

<sup>3</sup>Two or more, really: Git supports the concept of an *octopus merge*.  But there's no need to go there. :-)

#### Merge changes the graph from a tree to a DAG

Merges—true merges: commits with two or more parents—have a bunch of important—critical, even—side effects.  The main one is that the presence of a merge causes the commit graph data structure to change from a *tree*, where branches simply fork off and grow on their own, into a DAG: a Directed Acyclic Graph.

When Git walks the graph, as it does for so many operations, it usually follows *all* paths back.  Since a merge has two parents, `git log`, which walks the graph, shows both parent commits.  Hence this is considered a Feature:

> For example, rather than a single "Merge  into Master" or "Merge Master into ", git will add all the commit messages.

Git is following, and hence logging, both the original commit sequence—commits `H`, `G`, `E`, `D`, and so on—*and* the merged-in commit sequence `F`, `E`, `D`, and so on.  Of course, it shows each commit only once; and by default, it *sorts* these commits by their date-stamps, intermingling the two branches if each one has many commits with dates that overlap.

If you *don't want to see* the commits that came in via the "other side" of a merge, Git has a way to do that: `--first-parent` tells every Git command that walks the graph<sup>1</sup> to follow only the *first* parent of each merge.  The other side is still there in the graph, and it still affects how Git computes things like the merge base, but `git log --first-parent` won't *show* it.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is quite a lot of Git commands.  They use, or in the case of `git log` itself, *are*, variants of `git rev-list`, which is Git's general purpose graph-walk program.  This code is central to push, fetch, bisect, log, blame, rebase, and numerous others.  Its documentation has a dizzying array of options.  The key ones to know as a casual user are `--first-parent` (just discussed here); `--no-walk` (suppresses graph walking entirely); `--ancestry-path` (simplifies history for source tree related work); `--simplify-by-decoration` (simplifies history for `git log` output); `--branches`, `--remotes`, and `--tags` (selects starting points for graph walking by branch, remote, or tag name); `--merges` and `--no-merges` (include or exclude merge commits); `--since` and `--until` (limit commits by date ranges); and the basic `..` and `...` (two and three dot) graph subsetting operations.

#### Benefits of merges

Having the merge in place means that development on a branch can *continue* on that branch, and a later `git merge` finds a newer—and hence less complicated—merge base.  Consider this graph, where only a few commits have single-letter names:

```
  o--o--o--o--H--o--o--I        <-- feature2
 /             \        \
A--o--B---C-----D--E-----F--G   <-- master
 \       /        /        /
  o--o--J--o--o--K--o--o--L     <-- feature1
```

Here, except for two early commits done on `master` after the root commit `A`, all development has taken place on side branches `feature1` and `feature2`.  Commits `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G` are all merges (in this case, strictly into `master`), bringing the feature-work into `master` when it was ready.

Note that when we made commit `C` on `master`, we did:

```
$ git checkout master; git merge feature1
```

which found `A` as the merge base and `B` and `J` as the two tip commits to merge.  When we made `D`:

```
$ git checkout master; git merge feature2
```

we had `A` as the merge base and `C` and `H` as the two tip commits.  So far, this is nothing special.  But when we made `E`, we had this much so far (the final `o`s, and even `I`, on `feature2` may or may not have been in place—they have no effect):

```
  o--o--o--o--H--o--o           <-- feature2
 /             \
A--o--B---C-----D               <-- master
 \       /
  o--o--J--o--o--K              <-- feature1
```

The merge base of `master` and `feature1` is the first commit that is on *both* branches, which is commit `J`, which is the one we merged in to make `C`.  So to do this merge, Git compares `J` vs `D`—the code we brought in from `feature2`—and `J` vs `K`: the *new* code (and only the new code) on `feature1`.  If all goes well, or once we fix merge conflicts, this makes commit `E` and we now have:

```
  o--o--o--o--H--o--o--I        <-- feature2
 /             \
A--o--B---C-----D--E            <-- master
 \       /        /
  o--o--J--o--o--K--o--o        <-- feature1
```

when we go to merge `feature2` again.  This time the merge base is commit `H`: moving straight back from `feature2` soon hits `H`, and moving from `E` to `D` and then up to `H` from `master` also hits `H`.  So now Git compares `H` vs `E`, which is what we brought in from `feature1`, and `H` vs `I`, which is the *new* stuff we added to `feature2`, and merges just those.

#### Drawbacks of merges

Trees have some very nice graph-theoretic properties, such as a guarantee of a single simple merge-base.  Arbitrary DAGs may lose these properties.  In particular, doing merges both ways—merging `master` into `branch` *and* merging `branch` into `master`—results in "criss cross merges" that can give you multiple merge bases.

Merges also make the graph (`git log`) very hard to follow.  Using `--first-parent` or `--simplify-by-decoration` helps, especially if you practice good merging, but these graphs just naturally get messy.

#### Squash merges

Squash merges avoid the problems, but do so by paying a fairly heavy price: they are not merges at all.  (Soon, we'll see how to deal with this.)

When you run `git merge --squash`, Git goes through the same motions as before in terms of finding a merge base, and making two diffs: merge-base vs current-commit, and merge-base vs other-commit.  It then *combines* the changes in exactly the same way as for a regular commit.  But then it makes an *ordinary* commit.<sup>1</sup>  The new commit has just a single parent, taken from the current branch.

Let's see that in action for the same sequence with `feature1` and `feature2`:

```
  o--o--o                       <-- feature2
 /
A--o--B                         <-- master
 \ 
  o--o--J                       <-- feature1
```

We do `git checkout master; git merge --squash feature1` to make new commit `C`.  Git compares `A` vs `B` to see what we did on `master`, and `A` vs `J` to see what they (we) did on `feature1`.  Git combines those changes and we get commit `C`, but with only one parent:

```
  o--o--o                       <-- feature2
 /
A--o--B---C                     <-- master
 \
  o--o--J                       <-- feature1
```

Now we'll make `D` as a squash from `feature2`:

```
  o--o--o--o--H                 <-- feature2
 /
A--o--B---C                     <-- master
 \
  o--o--J--o--o                 <-- feature1
```

Git compares `A` vs `C`, and `A` vs `H`, same as last time.  We now get `D`.  So far it's much the same, except that there are no points where the branches rejoin.  But now it is time to make `E`:

```
  o--o--o--o--H--o--o           <-- feature2
 /
A--o--B---C-----D               <-- master
 \
  o--o--J--o--o--K              <-- feature1
```

We run `git checkout master; git merge --squash feature1` as before.

Last time, Git compared `J`-vs-`D` and `J`-vs-`K`, as commit `J` was our merge base.

This time, commit `A` is (still) our merge base.  Git compares `A` vs `D`, and `A` vs `K`.  If there were conflicts we solved at `C` last time, we probably have to solve them again.  This is bad—but we're not lost yet.

---

<sup>1</sup>Ordinary, as opposed to merge.  As such, a squash merge is not a merge at all: it's a "get me the *work done*" commit, but it's not a *merge* commit.  We need a *real* merge commit *in addition*; we will get to this in the next section.

Git actually stops here and forces you to run `git commit` to make the squash commit.  Why?  Who knows, it's Git. :-)

#### Squash merges *can* work

To solve the above, we just need to *re-merge* (with a *non*-squash "real merge") from `master` back to the `feature` branches.  That is, instead of simply merging from whichever feature branch into `master`, and then continuing to work on the feature branch, we do this:

```
  o--o--o--o--H--*-o--o        <-- feature2
 /              /
A--o--B---C----D               <-- master
 \         \
  o--o--J---*--o--o--K         <-- feature1
```

These new commits, marked `*`, are (non-squash) merges *from* master, *into* `feature1` and `feature2`.  We made squash merge `C` to pick up changes made from `A` to `J`.  So we then make a real merge into `feature1`, preferably using the tree straight from `master`<sup>1</sup> (which has whatever goodies were in `o--B--` as well).  (We also made the `*` on `feature2`, just as general preparation, after making `D` on `master` to bring in everything from `A` to `H`.  Like the `*` on `feature1` we probably just want the source tree straight from `master`.)

Now that we're ready to bring in more work from `feature1`, we can just do another (squash) merge.  The merge-base of `master` and `feature1` is commit `C`, and the two tips are `D` and `K`, which is just what we want.  Git's merge code will come up with a reasonably close result; we fix up any conflicts, test, fix any breakage, and commit; and then we do another "prep work" merge *from* `master` back *into* `feature1` as before.

This work-flow is a bit more complicated than the "merge into master" one, but *should* give good results.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git does not make this totally trivial: we want a merge with a `-s theirs` strategy, which Git simply doesn't have.  There *is* an easy way to get the desired effect using "plumbing" commands, but I'll leave that out of this answer, which is already crazy-long.

#### So, if that all works, how about the mechanics?

Note that what we want is `merge --squash` when merging *into* master, but regular (non-squash) merge when merging *from* master.  In other words:

```
$ git checkout master && git merge foo
```

should use `--squash`, but:

```
$ git checkout foo && git merge master
```

should *not* use `--squash`.  (The tree copying from the footnote in the previous section might be nice, but should be unnecessary: the merge result should basically always be the tree straight out of `master`.)

When `git merge` runs, it looks at the current branch (as it always must).  If that branch has a name—if we're not in "detached HEAD" mode—Git then looks at your configuration, for a value stored under `branch.branch.mergeOptions`.  Any string value here is scanned as if it were part of the `git merge` command.

Hence:

```
$ git config branch.master.mergeOptions "--squash"
```

(the quotes are not technically required, and you can add `--global` after `git config`, before `branch.master.mergeOptions`) sets up your current repository to do squash-merges into `master`.  (With `--global`, it sets this as your personal default for all repositories.  Any `branch.master.mergeOptions` set in a particular repository will override these global ones, though.)

Comment: td,dr: $ git config branch.master.mergeOptions "--squash"

Comment: @Joanvo: yeah, I tried to make that clear up front with the "skip to the end" bit...

Comment: I went ahead and added the command at the top, with the rest of the post labeled as the "explanation"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a bash shell command alias like so

```
alias gmg='git merge --squash'
```

Further, I didnt want the change to be staged automatically either so ended up creating the following bash function

```
gitmerge() {
        git merge --squash "$1"
        git restore --staged .
}
```