# How to generate a log entry on master when creating and deleting a dev branch?

Tags: git, logging, git-log

I'm trying to close an Audit and C&A gap in our processes. Our master is stable, and the typical workflow for feature development is (1) create dev branch, (2) develop on dev branch, (3) merge dev branch into master, (4) delete dev branch.

The logging we are trying to achieve on Master for the lifecycle is for the events:

1. Create dev branch
2. Merge dev branch into Master
3. Delete dev branch

We have Event 2 already. When we merge a dev branch into master, we use `--squash` to ensure the logs on dev during development [do not pollute master](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37352976). For example, we ***don't*** want Master to have *"Fix memory bug"* when Master never suffered it.

How do I generate a log entry on master when creating a dev branch (Event 1) and deleting a dev branch (Event 3)?

Or, should I back up and ask, is a dev branch the proper tool for feature development?

Comment: The only way to get a real `git log` entry (a log *message*) is to make a commit.  If you want a commit for its message, but Git is stubbornly refusing to make a commit because it's "empty" (this is the wrong name: it's not *empty*, it's just *identical*), you can simply use `--allow-empty`. Beware: this creates issues with a later `git rebase`; but if you only do this on `master` and never rebase `master`, those will never come up. Meanwhile, consider `git notes`, and see the long answer I made on your linked question.

Comment: Why not simply use `git log --first-parent` to ignore all log messages from your dev-branches?

Comment: We [stopped using Git development branches](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/WvyI6Z63z1I/8xM9cAqRBAAJ). All of these problems are now solved. I cast the first close vote using the reason ***Problem can no longer be reproduced***.