# Git: How to avoid intermediate commits of the merged develop branch into Master?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I'm new to GIT and I want to how to avoid intermediate commits say `D1-D2-D3` from `develop` getting added to `master` branch on `git merge`?

For e.g.

```
A-B-C(master) & D1-D2-D3-D4(develop) 

_on merge becomes_ 

A-B-C-D1-D2-D3-D4(master)
```

It should look like `A-B-C-D4(master)` on `merge`. Ideally I prefer `A-B-C-E(master)` where E is a new commit that is a `merge` commit, merge of `develop` onto `master`.

I tried `git merge --no-ff develop` and though it adds the new commit however all the intermediate commits also gets added to `master`.

Comment: The only way is to rewrite history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use git merge --squash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash)

Answer (score 1):

Use squash merge: `git merge --squash develop`.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Easier (albeit risky) way is to soft reset all the newer commits and create one commit containing all the changes.

```
git checkout develop
git reset HEAD~n   # n is the number of commits you want to merge together.
git commit -am "D4"
```

**Method 2 (preferable)**

Commonly used approach is to `squash` commits in develop branch, before merging/rebasing it into master.

```
git checkout develop
git rebase -i master

# This will open the editor and let you squash/edit the commits as applicable. For instance
pick 8705209 D1
squash 7979797 D2
squash 9793757 D3 # Use squash to squash commits into the previous one.
# add the final commit message

git checkout master
git rebase develop
```

[Rewriting git history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)