# How to put other repository changes to my repository like a commit?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a repository what is a local repository based on this repository https://github.com/AshamaneProject/AshamaneCore

I want to merge all their commits to my repository as a single commit with all the changes, how can i do it?

Im using ubuntu 17

Comment: " as a single commit with all the changes" - this statement is contradictory. If it's a single commit then you lose change history. Change history is a series of commits.

Comment: @Dai hello thanks for your answer, im not triying to dont preserve the history i just want to merge their changes to my repo to keep my repo updated with their changes

Comment: Sounds like you want a Git Submodule then: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: You used `repository` three times in a single sentence.  Cool.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im from Spain sorry, english is not my native language..

Comment: @Dai Could you please help me a bit more?

Comment: Could you please explain your use case in more detail? Are you referring to rebase: But that's a series of commits or you are referring to merge requests?

Comment: @ArihantGodha Hello, thanks for your help. I have a local copy from this repo (https://github.com/AshamaneProject/AshamaneCore) in a private repository where im doing some changes to this code but i want to merge their changes to have their changes in my own private repo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309051/2303202

Comment: Yep, you can use squash or you may consider using the repo mirroring and push to a remote functionality of GitLab
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a local repo with all the files in that repo, but you want your repo to have only one commit, that adds all their content at once?
Then you can just clone the repo, remove the `.git/` directory, init a new directory and add all the files and create that single commit.

If you already have a bunch of stuff and want to add theirs, you should probably fetch their stuff without merging it, and then do some kinda squash merge.
So basically like this:

1. Add the remote
2. Fetch the branch you want to merge
3. Check out the branch you want to add their stuff to
4. Merge using something like `git merge <remote>/<branch> --squash` (I'm not perfectly sure about the syntax for squash)

This should also handle any divergent history, so that only the new commits they have made are included in the squashed commit.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand your problem, you'd like to make a clean copy of another repo and push to your own repo. If it was me, I'd do it like this:

> 1. git clone / download as zip
> 2. git init -> git remote add origin
> 3. git commit -am "initialize commit"
> 4. git push -u origin master

If you do a git clone, you can browser to the directory and delete `.git` folder (`$cd <path-to-project>; $rm -rf *.git` ) and continue from step 2.

By delete `.git` folder, you'll remove all previous commit/messages/logs, make it a clean new repo.

It's simply as this:

> 1. $git clone <#repo-url#> . (the dot is to clone to current directory, which should be empty)
> 2. rm -rf .git
> 3. (start from step #2 above)