# Git: Rebase Last 5 Commits When 2 Are Merges

Tags: git

I've made a feature branch where the last entries in my `git log` are 3 commits and 2 merges.

The merges look like:

`Merge branch 'my_feature_branch' of my_repo into 'my_feature_branch'`

and

`Merge branch 'master' of my_repo into 'my_feature_branch'`

Normally, if I had 5 commits and wanted to turn them into one, I would just do `git rebase -i HEAD~5`.  However, when I try this, it tells me it couldn't apply the very first commit (not merge) listed in `git log`.

Any idea what's happening here?

I'd just like to neaten these 3 commits and 2 merges into a single commit to make a neat PR.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand the part about *"Merge branch 'my_feature_branch' of my_repo into 'my_feature_branch'"*... why do you merge from `my_feature_branch` into `my_feature_branch`? Anyway, what about `git merge --squash`? I think rebase is not really your scenario. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

Don't even try to do this.  You can rebase most commits, but you should not attempt to rebase *merge* commits.  The `git rebase` command *skips* (omits) the merge commits, as you no doubt saw when you ran `git rebase -i`.

You are safest if you rebase *unpublished* commits, which for most people in most workflows, means commits that you have not had `git push` send upstream yet.

As a sort of general rule, rebasing makes it unnecessary to *use* merge commits, except perhaps for one final merge.  This should all make more sense after reading the long answer below.

## Long

You cannot rebase a merge commit.

This is a slight overstatement: there is a form of `git rebase`, namely `git rebase --preserve-merges`, that purports to *preserve* merge commits while doing a rebase.  However, this claim that `git rebase --preserve-merges` makes is itself a lie!  It actually *re-performs* merges.  It's tricky to use correctly.

To understand all of this properly, start with these Git concepts:

- Every Git commit—really, every Git object—is immutable.  Nothing can change anything about any commit.  Each commit gets its own unique hash ID.  (Git adds a time-stamp to each commit so that as long as time increases, you will still get a new, unique ID.<sup>1</sup>)
- Most commits have exactly one *parent* commit.  Each commit lists all its parents, however many there are, by their hash IDs.
- A commit with more than one parent is a *merge commit*.  (A commit with *no* parents is a *root* commit; typically there are very few of these, although the very first commit made must always be a root commit, so there has to be one!)
- Git finds the *last* commit on a branch by reading the branch name.  The name simply contains the actual hash ID of that final commit.  Git then works backwards when necessary by using the last commit's parent(s), and those parents' parents, and so on.
- Any commit can be *copied*, by extracting it, making some alteration as appropriate, and making a new commit.  The new commit gets a new (different, unique-to-it) hash ID.  We'll make use of this in a moment.
- Writing a *new* commit to the current branch consists of the following process:

  1. Turn the current index into a snapshot.  You can do this yourself at any time using `git write-tree`.  This produces a *tree* object hash ID (which is not necessarily unique, since this snapshot might be the same as some other snapshot).
  2. Use the resulting tree hash ID, plus the metadata that goes into a commit—your name, your email address, the time stamp, etc.—to write a commit.  The *parent* hash ID in this new commit is taken out of the *current* commit, as stored in the branch name.  This is what the plumbing command `git commit-tree` does.  Like `git write-tree`, this produces a hash ID (unique this time).
  3. Write the *new* commit's hash ID into the current branch name.

---

<sup>1</sup>The granularity of the time stamp is in seconds, so it's technically possible to make the exact same commit twice, on two different branch names, within one second and get only one commit.  If you do that—e.g., via script—you get just the one commit, with the one hash ID.  The effect is essentially the same as `git merge --ff-only`.  Everything still works, but it's disconcerting!

---

The result of all of this is that for a simple linear chain of commits, we have a branch name—which we can draw at the right edge of the line—that *points to* (contains the hash ID of) the *tip* (last) commit of the branch.  That commit points backwards to its parent: its predecessor commit, which at one point *was* the tip of the branch.  The parent points back to *its* parent, and so on:

```
... <-parent <-tip   <-- branch
```

Because the commits are immutable once made, only *branch names* change.  These pointers move around all the time.  The others are fixed once made, and always point backwards, so we can just draw them as lines, which is handy in text: it lets us draw branches like this:

```
...--F--G---H--I   <-- master
         \
          J--K--L   <-- dev
```

Using this, we can now see how `git merge` works: we pick a branch, attach the word `HEAD` to it (using `git checkout`) so that Git knows *which* branch is the current one, and then run `git merge` on the other name.  Git finds the *merge base* commit—the point where the two branches rejoin, which in this case is commit `G`—and, in effect, runs two separate `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-G> <hash-of-I>   # what we changed on master
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-G> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed on dev
```

Git combines the two sets of changes, applying the *combined* changes to the snapshot stored in commit `G`, and if that all works, Git makes a new *merge commit* that uses this combined-changes snapshot.  The merge commit has *two* parents instead of just one.  The first parent is the commit that was `HEAD`, i.e., `I`, and the second is the other commit we just named, i.e., `L`:

```
...--F--G---H--I--M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          J--K--L   <-- dev
```

Note that the combining is smart: if we and they both made the *same* change(s) to the *same* line(s) of the same files, Git takes just one copy of those changes.  If we made conflicting changes to the same lines, the merge stops in the middle, leaving us to clean up the mess.  (We'll quietly pretend this never happens, for now. :-) )

#### Rebase copies commits, as if via repeated `git cherry-pick`

What `git rebase` is all about, fundamentally, is *copying* some set of commits.  That is, we'll do `git checkout dev && git rebase master` and Git will *copy* some set of commits.

For instance, instead of making merge commit `M`, what if we somehow got Git to copy the effect of commit `J`, but applied to the *snapshot* associated with commit `I`?  That is, we want to turn the snapshot in `J` into a set of changes, as compared to `J`'s parent commit `G`:

```
git diff <hash-of-G> <hash-of-J>   # what we did
```

If Git were then to *combine* those changes with the changes we made from `G` up through `I`, why then, we'd have just what we want.

Git *can* do this, and in fact, this *copy one commit* operation is available through the command `git cherry-pick`.  Note that this can be described a lot more simply as *apply `G` vs `J` as a patch to `I`*, and in many cases this description is adequate (so you can carry it around in your head as an approximation), but in fact, Git does it the same way it does the change-combining of `git merge`.  This means that if commit `I` already has some of the same work as `G`-vs-`J`, the copy is smart, just like `git merge`: we get just one copy of the change, instead of two.

The final result, though, is an ordinary non-merge commit that is *like* `J`, but different in two ways:

- It starts with whatever was in `I`, not with whatever was in `G` (and omits any duplicated changes).
- It has, as its parent, commit `I`, not commit `G`.

So let's call this new commit `J'`, and draw it in.  Git makes this new commit using Git's "detached HEAD" mode, where the special name `HEAD` points directly to a commit, but you can think of this as Git using a temporarily-unnamed branch:

```
                J'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
         \
          J--K--L   <-- dev
```

Now that `J` has been copied to `J'`, `git rebase` proceeds by copying commit `K` to `K'`, using the same core `git cherry-pick` idea.<sup>2</sup>  This time the merge base is commit `J` rather than commit `G`, but if all goes well we don't really have to care about these details, we just see the copy completing and producing:

```
                J'-K'  <-- HEAD
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
         \
          J--K--L   <-- dev
```

Finally, rebase copies `L` to `L'`, then executes its final trick: it peels the branch name `dev` away from original commit `L`, and makes it point to the last commit in the new chain, `L'`.  It re-attaches `HEAD` at the same time, so that we have this:

```
                J'-K'-L'  <-- dev (HEAD)
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
         \
          J--K--L   [abandoned]
```

The newly copied commits have new and different hash IDs, but serve the same *purpose* as the originals, and share their commit messages.  Because Git does not display the abandoned original commits,<sup>3</sup> it *looks like* the originals have mysteriously changed.  In fact, though, they are still there and can be restored if desired; we just have the name `dev` now locating the copied tip commit `L'` instead of the original tip `L`.

Since the copied commits come *after* `master`, it's now trivial to use a *fast-forward* operation to incorporate those new commits without any actual merging.  A fast-forward really means *move the name forward, opposite the direction that the internal backwards commit arrows go*.  We can take this:

```
                J'-K'-L'  <-- dev
               /
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

and just slide the name `master` up-and-right so that it points to commit `L'` too:

```
                J'-K'-L'  <-- dev, master
               /
...--F--G--H--I
```

and it looks like we somehow managed to write all our commits in the best possible order.  We only need an actual merge if we really want one; and to do that in plain Git, we have to run `git merge --no-ff`.

**Note: GitHub's clicky merge button runs `git merge --no-ff` automatically, or runs `git rebase` first and then does a fast-forward, or runs `git merge --squash`, which we haven't covered here.  This is all quite a bit different from command-line Git.**

---

<sup>2</sup>For historical reasons, `git rebase -i` actually *uses* `git cherry-pick`, and some other `git rebase` modes such as `git rebase -m` do as well, but some `git rebase` modes use `git format-patch` piped to `git apply`.  This means that some rebases will fail to pick up on file renames, and can hit a few other corner cases.  Probably rebase should default to cherry-pick style all the time, and only offer the patch-and-apply method with a backwards compatibility switch.  But most of the time they work the same anyway.

<sup>3</sup>At this point, they are not truly abandoned.  They can be found through two *reflogs:* one for the branch name `dev` and one for `HEAD`; and also via the special name `ORIG_HEAD`.  Within about 30 days, though, the reflog entries will expire, and something will have overwritten `ORIG_HEAD` with some other previous branch-tip ID, and those commits will be truly abandoned and will be taken out by Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`.

---

#### Cherry-picking a merge commit is hard

To do a `git cherry-pick` operation, Git had to look at the *parent* of the commit to be copied.  An ordinary commit has only one parent, so this is easy: *the* parent is the parent.  A merge commit, however, has *two* (or more but we're only concerned with two here).  Which parent should `git cherry-pick` use?

When you do a cherry-pick yourself, what Git does for these is that it forces you to pick one.  For rebase, however, Git just *omits* the parents from the list of commits to copy.

What this means that if you already merged `master` into `dev`, as in this drawing (note that the merge `M` is on `dev` and not `master`, and `HEAD` is attached to `dev`):

```
...--F--G---H----I   <-- master
         \        \
          J--K--L--M   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

you can still just run `git rebase <options> master`.  This has Git find the commits that are *reachable*<sup>4</sup> from `dev`—it's the current branch, to which `HEAD` is attached—that are not reachable from `master`, while throwing away merges.  That list consists of the same commits as before: `J`, `K`, and `L`!

If the rebase works, you get the same picture as before, with `dev` pointing to `L'`, which points back to `K'` and `J'` and then `I`.  Commit `M` is no longer *useful* since the three copied commits *start from* the snapshot in `I`.

Since the point of rebasing a simple, linear chain of commits is (normally) to put the whole chain *after* some other commit, it makes sense to throw out merges.  Git *can't* copy them with a simple `git cherry-pick`, and it won't need to anyway.  But there are some cases where you might like to keep some merge commits.

---

<sup>4</sup>For a good definition of *reachable*, with a digestible dose of graph theory, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

---

#### `git rebase --preserve-merges`

For the special case of taking several non-linear chains (with embedded merges) and copying them, Git does have the `--preserve-merges` or `-p` option.  However, this does not actually *preserve* merges.  What it does—through a hack that really isn't quite right—is to generate an internal script that remembers where various merges *were*, then use the `git rebase -i` machinery to copy commits, stopping whenever it would have had to copy a merge.

At these points, instead of attempting to copy the merge commit, Git just runs a *new* `git merge`.  Unfortunately, this new merge does not know what options were used for the original `git merge`.  If you did in fact use options (e.g., `-s ours`, `-X ours`, or `--find-renames=20`), Git fails to use those same options and the merge may well go awry (of course it might go awry just like any merge).  Using `git rerere` can get one past some sticking points here, but in general this is quite tricky.  You must carefully check the results of any re-performed merges.

This will be much improved in Git 2.18, although I have not looked at the details yet (and I suspect there is still no provision for remembering merge options: that requires auxiliary data Git could save, but does not currently save anywhere).

#### Summary

This is not everything that you can do with rebase (we have not touched on `--onto` nor on the various commands you can do in an interactive rebase), but it covers the key elements:

- Rebase involves copying some set of commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`.
- These omit merge commits.
- To see which commits will be copied, to where, draw the graph!  (Or use `git log --graph`, perhaps with `--oneline` and additional options, or use a viewer like `gitk` or one of the GUIs that draws the graph.)
- After copying, you only need a merge if you really *want* one.  The copied commits generally come after the tip of the target branch, making everything ready for a fast-forward instead.

It's also important to remember that GitHub works differently from Git.  The clicky web button can do three different things, and only one of them is `git merge` (and even then it's `git merge --no-ff`!).

Comment: "You cannot rebase a merge commit." Well... actually, even better than the `-p` (`--preserve-merges`)  option, you now (Git 2.18) have the `--rebase-merges` option! (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309)

Comment: @VonC: Ah, yes, I should update! (I don't have 2.18 installed anywhere yet)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want to do, reset your feature branch to master, and commit all your changes again as a single commit:

```
git checkout my_feature_branch
git branch backup
git reset master
git add ... # all your changes
git commit -m '...' # write a nice message
git diff backup # should not show any difference
git branch -D backup
git push origin my_feature_branch --force
```