# The correct git workflow for changes after pull request

Tags: git, workflow, pull-request

What is the recommended git workflow is the this situation:

We have a 2-people dev team. I have made a branch of my own
and rebased it to correspond with the main branch. I create
a pull request; my colleague reviews the code and finds something
to correct. I correct it and push; meanwhile, she finds another
point that needs to be changed. After several changes, the pull
request is ready to be merged to main.

However, the history now looks like this:

```
Fixed Error X
Fixed Error Y
Added thing Z

Issue XX: Doing YY.
```

whereas I'd like it just to be

```
Issue XX: Doing YY.
```

Normally, this can be conveniently solved by something like

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Now, however, while this is still possible to do, it creates
a merge conflict with the branch already pushed to git.
This can be overcome by *--force* of course, but I am reluctant
to do this, as I'm sure there must be a more elegant way. What
would it be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge multiple commits onto another branch as a single squashed commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-can-i-merge-multiple-commits-onto-another-branch-as-a-single-squashed-commit)

Comment: I want to challenge your assumption that you actually want to join these commits. Because the benefits of having individual, separate commits are vastly superior. Reading the history is easier digestible, you can pinpoint things more accurately with [git-bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect), conflicts are less likely (and easier to resolve if they occur) when rebasing, etc. Why do you want to squash those commits? The **only** reason people are giving for doing so is to use squash as a deodorant to cover up that the history stinks. But that is not a good reason. Fix the history then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Just using squash

If you just want to squash the whole branch then the simplest alternative
is to use your forge’s squash merge button (like GitHub’s).

A squash merge will never create a merge conflict if a normal merge would
have not created a merge conflict. So what you write here is not true:

> Now, however, while this is still possible to do, it creates a merge
> conflict with the branch already pushed to git.

What happens is that you try to push a branch when you have rewritten the
history. And that will always require `--force`.[1] There is no more
elegant way (so-called) to do it if your workflow is:

1. Do a squash locally
2. Push the branch
3. Merge from the web pull request view

But if you do a squash merge from GitHub (or whatever forge) then you
don’t have to force push your branch.

#### Using rebase (a superset of squash)

*Squash* is a sledgehammer and you can do more interesting things with the
full power of git-rebase(1).

Let’s say the PR starts like this (not commit messages, just descriptions):

```
3: Fix #987654
2: Fix typos
1: Formatting: tabs to spaces
```

I set out to fix #987654. Then I saw that there were some other things in
my way:

1. The file uses tabs for indentation, which is not the project standard
2. Typos in functions and variables in the code that I’m about to change

So I do those first. Then when they are out of the way I can do the thing
I was sent here to do.

Then I get PR feedback. They find bugs in my fix. So then the history
becomes:

```
6. Make adjustments for #987654 in another module
5: Fix test suite regression
4: Fix off-by-one error that I made
3: Fix #987654
2: Fix typos
1: Formatting: tabs to spaces
```

(5) was caused by me not updating a unit test which covers the code that I
fixed.

(6) was about a reviewer noticing that #987654 has some subtle behavior in
a different module that I didn’t catch.

Now the review is done. And now the question becomes: what’s history that
I want to merge?

I don’t want to keep (4) and (5) since these were work-in-progress
mistakes that will have no value to the permanent history. (This is a
judgement call.)

I want to keep everything else:

- (1) and (2) are preliminary work that has nothing to do with #987654 but
  needed to be done before I could do #987654
- (6) is pretty subtle and non-obvious. So in addition to a small code
  comment I want to document that change in its own commit message

So I want this history:

```
Fix #987654 in module b
Fix #987654 in module a
Fix typos
Formatting: tabs to spaces
```

Which means that the `git rebase --interactive` todo list becomes
something like:

```
pick Formatting: tabs to spaces
pick Fix typos
pick Fix #987654
fixup Fix off-by-one error that I made
fixup Fix test suite regression
pick Make adjustments for #987654 in another module
```

#### Notes

1. Or `--force-with-lease` or something even (somewhat) safer