# How to resolve easy merge conflicts automatically in Git

Tags: git, jetbrains-ide, git-merge-conflict

My code locally:

```
    disableCaching()
    setupGoogleMaps()
```

Change from remote:

```
    disableCaching()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    initializeNotificationService()
    setupGoogleMaps()
```

For me, it seems obvious that two lines have been added above `setupGoogleMaps()`

But why does git prompt me to fix this conflict manually?

[image]

Is there a tool that can fix those easy conflicts automatically?

I already tried the magic icon for resolving simple conflicts but this is not working in this case.

[image]

I was able to reproduce it with this repo:

https://github.com/tolotrasamuel/easy-conflict

1. `git checkout featurebranch`
2. `git pull origin/master`

Comment: What's the conflicting part like?

Comment: The problem isn't solving your particular easy case properly, it's identifying when something that looks like your easy case can't be solved that way. It's better to let humans make the judgment calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a tool that can fix those easy conflicts automatically?

Not really, no. The reason Git is turning to you for help is exactly that "automatically" performing the merge isn't working.

The reasons why Git needs help here when you think it shouldn't, is that Git is taking more than one line into account in deciding where the hunks are. You compare

```
disableCaching()
setupGoogleMaps()
```

With

```
disableCaching()
FirebaseApp.configure()
initializeNotificationService()
setupGoogleMaps()
```

And you say "it seems obvious that two lines have been added". But:

- Those are *different and equally weighted contributions* to the merge; i.e., it is *not* the case that the second one is laid on top of the first, but rather that *both* of them have to be laid somehow on top of what was *originally* present, which was just the line `disableCaching`.
- To Git, the single pair of lines in the first code counts as just one hunk — and, seen that way, it is clear different from the same hunk in the second code.

My advice in this situation would be:

1. Don't look for a "tool". Just resolve the conflict and move on. And
2. Don't use a GUI for this, just jump in and edit the conflicted text file by hand. I think you'll find that's a *lot* easier. And it's easier to understand, too.

Here's what we get using the `diff3` mode:

```
setupInstabug()
setupAppCenter()
<<<<<<< HEAD
disableCaching()
setupGoogleMaps()
||||||| a19174f
disableCaching()
=======
disableCaching()
FirebaseApp.configure()
initializeNotificationService()
setupGoogleMaps()
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

The bit in the middle is what we originally had, namely, just the line `disableCaching`. Okay, so *one* branch, yours, wants to put

```
setupGoogleMaps()
```

after that. The *other* branch, `master`, wants to put

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
initializeNotificationService()
setupGoogleMaps()
```

And you're saying, fine, so why not just do both?

But to Git, there is no "both": those are two completely different things that might be added after your line, because `disableCaching` is a *unit* together with the following line. It doesn't see this the way you do. It's saying, "Which did you want: the one line, or the three lines?"  So since you know what's meant — namely, the three lines — simply edit the file to say so:

```
setupInstabug()
setupAppCenter()
disableCaching()
FirebaseApp.configure()
initializeNotificationService()
setupGoogleMaps()
```

Now say `git add .` and then `git merge --continue` and you're all set.

Comment: Turns out someone has merged their feature branch using squash merge, this created a recursive conflicts as shown in master branch. Solution was to tell the team to use Merge no fast forward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797904/git-merge-squash-and-recurring-conflicts

Comment: "Tell the team" is dangerous. A spoken contract is not worth the paper it's printed on. GitHub lets you enforce _rules_ about these things.

Comment: That would have been ideal, unfortunately, Github nor Azure does have a feature to limit merge type base on source branch, it can only be ruled out based on destination branch 
[epicMerged/*] -> [develop] [Rule: Merge no fast forward Only]
[hotFixMerged/*] -> [develop] [Rule: Merge no fast forward Only]
[developRebase/*] -> epic/*] [Rule: Merge no fast forward Only]
[feature/* , fix/*] -> [epic/*, release/*, develop] [Rule: Squash Only]

Comment: Darn! Yeah, I'm used to working in a world where the rule in GitHub is enforced across the board, i.e. there is only one button option available.