# git merge squash - conflict resolution when all I want is the changes from the branch I squashed from

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, squash

I have *github* branch which I push to github when the master branch reaches some acceptable state (have done this once). To this end I did :

```
MrD@MRSD /c/Dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/android/AndroidMonitoring (master)
$ git checkout github
Switched to branch 'github'
MrD@MRSD /c/Dropbox/eclipse_workspaces/android/AndroidMonitoring (github)
$ git merge --squash master
Auto-merging src/gr/uoa/di/monitoring/android/services/Monitor.java
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in src/gr/uoa/di/monitoring/android/services/
Monitor.java
//...
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

What I want is to just have the working directory *exactly* in the same state as in master HEAD.

- Is my way of doing this wrong (repeatedly merge --squashing into the github branch).
- Is there an easy, *idiot-proof* way to achieve this (without going through each conflict).
- As a bonus I would like to know what *Use Local Version* and *Use Remote Version* mean in this pic - msysgit:

  [image]

Comment: _I would like to know what Use Local Version and Use Remote Version mean in this pic - msysgit_: this is still a mystery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well after a lot of googling it turns out that my strategy was wrong. `git merge --squash` does not do what I want - namely mirroring my master branch to my github branch, without keeping the history of the commits in master (a plain merge would do but I did not want to have any of the master's history in github).
For one it does not delete deleted files - for a nice explanation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14343784/281545)
There are probably other pitfalls - including the eternal conflict resolution that [can't be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797904/git-merge-and-recurring-conflicts)

Anyway I think I found the correct way - the one detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4481621/281545)

```
$ git checkout master@{0}
$ git reset --soft github
$ git commit
$ git branch temp
$ git checkout temp
$ git branch -M github
$ git push -u -v  origin github:master
```

tried it and it does work as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow up the `git merge --squash` with a `git commit`, so there is a possible fault in your workflow.

You can use `git merge -s theirs` to specify that you always want the other, master branch in this case, to win all merge conflicts. (Though I am surprised you get merge conflicts if you do no separate work on the github branch)

Comment: To commit I have first to resolve the conflicts - but those merge conflicts is what I am after (and also wandering at)

Comment: If you have not committed anything but merges to the github branch, I would reset the current merge and start it over again. `git reset --merge` works nicely.

Comment: I does not make a difference - still the conflicts appear

Comment: If you are sure about wanting all the changes from master, then `git merge -s theirs` should resolve all conflicts. Have you tried that?

Comment: "I am surprised you get merge conflicts if you do no separate work on the github branch" - I was too - check the links in my answer

Comment: For those interested, here's a link to the git docs for the `merge` command and the different merge strategies you can specify with the `-s` merge strategy option used in this answer.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge/#_merge_strategies