# What is git diff origin master supposed to do?

Tags: git, diff

From a git branch, a colleague of mine ran

```
git diff origin master
```

What is it supposed supposed to do? What does `origin` separately point to?

This is related, but not covered in 
[In Git, what is the difference between origin/master vs origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This form of `git diff` just takes two revision specifiers, as described in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

In this case `origin` is most likely to match item 6:

> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

So this means the same as `git diff origin/HEAD master`: resolve `origin/HEAD` to a commit-ID, resolve `master` to a commit-ID, and diff the two commits.

Run:

```
git rev-parse origin
```

to see how the resolution works.

Comment: Is `fetch`  mandatory before this command ? or does it goes already to the remote repository and checks.... ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's not *required* that you run `git fetch` first, but if you don't, your Git is using the information saved from the *last* fetch (or perhaps updated by a previous `git push`). If you think new commits may have appeared on the remote since the last time your Git had a conversation with the remote, and you want to see those commits, run `git fetch` now to get your Git to talk to theirs now. Then, any time, use `origin/<name>` to refer to the information saved by this latest `git fetch`.

Comment: In other words , what is the fastest way to check if  there is a new version in the remote side? A fetch must be made then.... right?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: yes, you must contact the other Git, and `git fetch` is probably the simplest and easiest way to do so. You can use `git ls-remote` to do just the first step of fetch (obtain names and hash IDs) but if they *do* have new commits, you probably want the new commits anyway. Note that by the time you get an answer from them, your answer may be out of date: for instance, suppose it takes 2 seconds for packets to reach your machine, so you fetch and they say their `master` is a123456. That information is at least two seconds old: someone might have done a push one second ago!

Comment: The upshot of all of this is that It's sensible to do a `git fetch` first, but don't count on your information being up to date, no matter how recently you obtained it, unless you have a larger surrounding protocol. That's a fundamental problem in any distributed system: information you have, locally, may not match information they (whoever they are), have locally-to-them. You must build atomicity some other way, e.g., using compare-and-swap requests ("I think you think A=3, if so set A=4, and in any case, let me know what you did") or leases ("tell me A and don't change it for 30 seconds").

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Btw i never understood where in the 3 trees (working folder,index,repo) does fetch file are being downloaded to , if they aren't merged

Comment: `git fetch` doesn't download *files*. It obtains *objects* (typically commits+trees+blobs) and their hash IDs, and adds those objects to your repository. Your repository isn't a tree, though. It's bigger than a tree: it has one big database of all Git objects (of four types) which forms a directed acyclic graph, a smaller database that maps from names (branch names, tag names, and other references) to hash IDs, and some ancillary data. (Meanwhile your work-tree *is* a tree, and your index is a sort of flattened-out tree.)

Answer (score 3):

"origin" points to the "remote", typically where you cloned the repository from,
 see

```
$ git remote -v show
```

But specifically in answer to your question "git diff origin master" is equiv. to this:

```
$ git diff origin/HEAD master
```

origin/HEAD to the branch pointed to by HEAD reference on the remote. Which was the checked out branch at last pull.

Take a look at your commit graph, which will show you where all your references are (--decorate)

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate
```

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to

```
git diff origin/HEAD master
```

Answer (score 2):

It shows the changes between the tips of origin/HEAD and the master branches.
You can achieve the same with following commands:

- git diff origin/HEAD master
- git diff origin/HEAD..master

Usually origin points to the source from where you cloned your repository.

Answer (score 1):

It depends... if `origin` and `master` are branches, it shows the difference between them. When looking over explanations, they usually use `origin` to stand for the original (upstream, official, whatever) branch, and `master` for the branch you are working on. I.e., "show me what changed with respect to the original version."