# Difference between "git diff origin/somebranch" and "git diff origin somebranch"

Tags: git, github

What is the difference between these?

For example if I have just cloned a repo and there is a remotes/origin/somebranch

```
git checkout somebranch
```

make changes then add commit push

`git diff origin somebranch` is showing changes.

`git diff origin/somebranch` shows no changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have done `git push` that should make `origin/somebranch` and `somebranch` point to the same SHA, so I would not expect `git diff origin/somebranch` to show any differences, since that is diffing against `HEAD`, which is `somebranch`.  Try it after you commit and before you push to see your changes.

The reason that `git diff origin somebranch` is showing changes is due to how git is interpreting `origin`.  I'm guessing it is interpreting it to mean `origin/HEAD` from when it fetched the remote, and that the remote HEAD was something other than `somebranch`.  You can verify this by

```
git rev-parse origin
git name-rev origin
```

or from your top level directory and presuming your refs aren't packed

```
cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be good if you take a look at the below stack overflow question which explains what is the difference between 'origin master' and 'origin/master' .

[In Git, what is the difference between origin/master vs origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master)

and this link which explains how git tries to resolve the symbolic links

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html

so here

```
git diff origin/somebranch
```

is trying to compare the current index to origin/somebranch , which should have the same data as you have already committed your changes. ( pushing to the remote really doesn't make much difference as diff will not try to fetch data from the remote.)

on the other hand

```
 git diff origin somebranch
```

tries to compare the origin's HEAD (refer number :6 from the second link) with the branch somebranch (number:4 from the second link) . Normally a remotes head will be pointing to master branch ,so here it can be showing the differences between the master branch and the branch that you have mentioned