# git difference between origin/master and origin master

Tags: git

I seem to have a weird difference in origin/master

The commands are run in order

I am on the master branch and ran the commands in sequence

```
git pull origin master
```

**Same output:**

```
git diff origin/master 
git diff remotes/origin/master
```

**Different output:**

```
git diff origin/master
git diff origin master
```

Can someone explain why is this so?

Thanks.

Comment: `origin/master` is just a short name for `remotes/origin/master`, so it makes sense that they both give the same output. `git diff origin master` is the difference between `origin/master` and the local `master`; `git diff origin/master` is the difference between `origin/master` and the working tree. You didn’t actually say what any of the output was, though, so not sure what’s weird about it.

Comment: well the difference is that there were more changes observed in `git diff origin master` as opposed to `git diff origin/master`

Comment: So… do you have any changes in the working tree? (Run `git diff`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Git, what is the difference between origin/master vs origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master)

Comment: `git pull` is a weird command that will lead you astray. Avoid it for now—it's meant to be a convenient shortcut, `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, usually `git merge`. But it uses this peculiar spelling—`origin master`—in an unusual way that won't make sense yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have use `origin`, it itself means `origin/master` i.e. your master branch on remote server.
For specifying some other branch on remote server, you will need branch name. E.g origin/mybranch123.

And When you type `master`  (or any other branch name) alone, without origin you are referring to local branch.

Now correct way to see the diff is `git diff branch_name1 branch_name2`

So you see the actual result when you are typing the last command. 
In typing `git diff`origin/master you are just specificying 1 branch name.
Same is the case with `remotes/origin/master` as it is same as `origin/master`.