# Pulling changes for a branch from remote

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-pull

I'm currently working with 2 others engineers on the same branch. we're working of separate controllers(or just separate files), i'm unable to use `git pull origin/<Branch>` to update my branch with my teammate's commits.
Following error is shown:

```
fatal: 'origin/<Branch>' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I pull my teammate's changes?

P.S. is it good practice for different engineer's to be working on the same branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Git, what is the difference between origin/master vs origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master)

Comment: `git pull origin <Branch>`

Answer (score 1):

Try `git pull origin <Branch>` (no `/`) That's the syntax shown in [git-scm.com/docs/git-pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_examples).

In case an error about "origin" persists, try `git remote -v` to check if the URL you mean is indeed abbreviated as "origin" or maybe has a typo.