# Why can't I switch to another Github branch?

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm using Github. My friend created a branch called `broken_textures` in our repository, and I cannot figure out how to switch to that branch. I've tried `git pull origin/broken_textures` and many variations of that, but it keeps telling me the repository does not exist. The most success I had was `git checkout remotes/origin/broken_textures` which created a detached HEAD pointing to the branch. I just want to copy the branch onto my computer so I can work on it, and later I want to merge it into master. How am I supposed to do this, and what am I not understanding about the branching system?

Comment: Are you both collaborates on the same repository and did he push his feature branch to origin? Can your friend checkout your branches?

Comment: I'm not sure what those words mean, but we are using Github and both branches are listed on Github. Also when I run `git branch -a` in my terminal I see his branch listed as `remotes/origin/broken_textures`. I guess that means he did push his branch to origin, because I think origin means Github in this case.

Comment: What the output of `git branch -a` is?

Comment: do you have also trie with  `git checkout --track origin/broken_textures` ?

Comment: I just tried that and it seems to work, but I don't understand why I have to make a tracking branch instead of just fully switching to that branch.

Comment: The output of `git branch -a` is
`* broken_textures`, `master`, `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`, `remotes/origin/broken_textures`, `remotes/origin/master`, 
where the local `broken_textures` branch was just created by @SwissCodeMen's suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Git, what is the difference between origin/master vs origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking out a local branch from a remote branch automatically creates what is called a “tracking branch” (or sometimes an “upstream branch”). Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch. If you’re on a tracking branch and type `git pull`, Git automatically knows which server to fetch from and branch to merge into.

When you clone a repository, it generally automatically creates a `master` branch that tracks `origin/master`. However, you can set up other tracking branches if you wish – ones that track branches on other remotes, or don’t track the `master` branch. The simple case is the example you just saw, running `git checkout -b [branch] [remotename]/[branch]`. This is a common enough operation that git provides the `--track` shorthand:

`$ git checkout --track origin/BRANCH_NAME`

With `--track` you create a local branch. It depends on the **git version** whether you have to add `--track` or not (from Git 1.7.2.4 `git checkout BRANCH_NAME` is enough).

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches

Comment: After hours of research I finally understand, thank you.

Comment: well I'm glad if my answer helps you. Good success with git and the branches :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a branch which is not stored locally.  So you have to fetch the details from the remote,  create a local branch and it should be set to track the remote branch.  The easiest way is to do the following

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b broken_textures origin/broken_textures
```