# How is `Remote/Feature` Different from `remote feature`?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

When merging master into feature branches, I have always done

```
git merge origin master
```

It has always worked fine. However, I was peripherally aware that the syntax `origin/master` also exists, to specify which remote you want to use (I think). However this morning, I wanted a clean version of master so I deleted my local copy, and then `fetch`ed. Now when I do `git merge origin master` I receive the message

> ```
> Did you mean this?
>   origin/master
> ```

Do I need the forward slash? Why is git now requiring this? What are the differences between using it and not using it?

Comment: You probably were doing `git pull origin master`. The "pull" command takes a remote and branch. The merge command just takes refspecs (branches, commit Ids, tags, etc).

Comment: @GregBurghardt No I wasn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+difference+%22origin%2Fmaster%22+%22origin+master%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stuff *is* very confusing.  Git could be more consistent here, if enough of its commands had been written at the same time.  They weren't—these various operations were put together over the course of several years—and backwards compatibility limited the Git authors.

Let's define some terms:

- A *remote* is a short name, like `origin`.  The purpose of this short name is several-fold:

  1. It stores a URL, so that you don't have to keep typing it.  The URL might be `https://github.com/user/project.git` or `ssh://git@github.com/user/project.git` or something much longer, but the first remote name is almost always `origin` and that's only six letters, hence much easier to type.
  2. It acts as a prefix for *remote-tracking names*.

  A remote always represents some *other Git*.  That other Git is a full Git repository (although often it's a `--bare` repository, meaning it has no working tree).
- A *branch name* is a name like `master` or `topic` or `feature/short` or whatever.  There are some constraints on branch names—for instance, they may not contain two or more adjacent dots, so that `hello.world` is OK but `well...yes` is not.
- A *remote-tracking name* is a name like `origin/master` or `origin/topic`.  It's built out of two parts: a *remote name*, like `origin`, and a *branch name as seen on that other Git*.

When your Git calls up another Git, via a remote name like `origin`, your Git has that Git list out all of *its* branch names.  These branch names correspond to specific commits in that other Git repository.  Your Git will get these commits from that Git, if you don't already have them.  Then, your Git will remember *their* **branch** names by creating or updating **your** *remote-tracking* names.  So if their `master` represents commit `a123456`, your `origin/master` will now be updated to hold `a123456` too.

In general, Git can turn either a branch name like `master`, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`, into a commit hash ID.  Running:

```
git rev-parse master
```

will show you what hash ID your Git has for your `master` right now, for instance.

When you run `git merge`—which is an early command, predating even the existence of remote names like `origin`—what you need to give to it is name(s) of one or more commits.  So `git merge origin/master` suffices here, because `origin/master` names one specific commit.  `git merge topic` also suffices, if you have a branch named `topic`, because your branch name `topic` names one specific commit.

If you give `git merge` the names of two or more commits, Git will (well, sometimes will) perform what Git calls an *octopus merge*.  For instance:

```
git merge topic1 topic2 topic3
```

performs a merge that combines three topic branches with whatever your current branch is (perhaps `master`).

If you've been running:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin master
```

you have been asking Git to do one of these octopus merges.  The commit you're asking to merge is `origin`.

Now, `origin` itself is not a remote-tracking name.  But try running:

```
git rev-parse origin
```

as well as:

```
git rev-parse origin/master
```

You will almost certainly see that both commands produce the *same* commit hash ID.  The reason is that the name `origin` by itself, when used where Git expects a branch or remote-tracking name, is expanded to read `origin/HEAD`.  Then, `origin/HEAD` is expanded too, usually to `origin/master`.  So this winds up meaning `git merge origin/master master`.

Meanwhile, you are *already on your own `master`* so `git merge master` would not do anything anyway.  So this particular "octopus" merge collapses into a regular merge of your `master` with your `origin/master`, which is your Git's memory of some other Git's `master`.

In general you should use `git merge origin/master` here, to be explicit and not depend on `origin/HEAD` mapping to `origin/master`.  Moreover, you may want to make use of another Git feature, called the *upstream setting* of a branch name, so that you can just run `git merge` (without any extra names at all).  But it's been working because `origin` here got expanded to `origin/HEAD` which meant `origin/master`, and your octopus merge request got turned into a more ordinary merge in the end.

Note that the `git pull` command is quite different: it's meant as a convenience.  It runs `git fetch` first, then it runs a second Git command.  The default second Git command is `git merge`.  When it does the `git fetch` step, it needs a *remote*—a name like `origin`.  So the `origin` in `git pull origin master` is for `git fetch`.  Then, when it does the second step, it needs to know the name of the branch you wanted *as seen on the other Git*.  So the `master` in `git pull origin master` means *`master` as seen over on `origin`*, which your Git remembers as `origin/master` for non-`pull` commands like `git merge`.

That's where all this confusion comes from: `git pull` predates remotes, and you used to do things like `git pull url master`.  Here it was clear that the *`url`* part was to get to some other Git, and then `master` meant their `master`.  Remotes—like `origin`—didn't exist, and therefore remote-tracking names like `origin/master` didn't exist either.  Now they do, and we have the situation we have.

Comment: `git rev-parse master` => `fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` However, yes: `rev-parse`ing `origin` and `origin/master` got me the same hash. "Then, origin/HEAD is expanded too, usually to origin/master. So this winds up meaning git merge origin/master master.". This is really, really good information. I have always wondered about that. Thank you so much!

Comment: ¶ It looks to be simply like `master` "lost track" of the remote it was meant to track when I deleted it (no surprise). `git checkout master; git branch -u origin/master`, seems to have resolved the issue. This is a great answer. Lots to think about here. Thanks again.

Comment: If `git rev-parse master` came up with nothing at all, you've somehow deleted the branch name `master`. Deleting the branch name itself is mostly harmless. It does lose something important: the answer to the question *which commit was I using for my branch `master`?* But if the commit you were using is also the commit the *other* Git is using for *its* `master`, that information is enough!

Comment: When you run `git checkout master` and you don't have a branch named `master`, your Git checks through your remote-tracking names. If you have `origin/master` (and nothing else that looks too much like the name `master`), your Git says: *aha, you must want to **create** your `master` now* and so it does that, then checks out that commit, and you're all set.