# git remote 2x origin/master

Tags: git, github

Why are there two "origin/master" pointers (one at head is red, one at bottom is green)?

```
85ea9aa (HEAD -> master, origin/master) rewrote weight routines to include initialization
b511483 refactored mnist with globals
33a515e refactored naive to use model-ref dictionary for weights
c0253d2 reworked matrix build
ba654ea (origin/master) initial baseline of julia mnist implementation following Dogra
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Git, what is the difference between origin/master vs origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master)

Comment: No, there are 2 origin/master entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have accidentally created a local branch named `origin/master` (`refs/heads/origin/master` in full, while your remote-tracking branch is `refs/remotes/origin/master`). You can simply delete it with `git branch -d origin/master`.