# Which is "clones" counted in the Clone Graph, master or origin?

Tags: git-clone

When I did "git clone", the Clone Graph shows "unique cloner=1 and clones=2".
Tell me why pls.

Answer (score 0):

your question is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18137175/9484913)

it's duplicated.

There are actually three things here: `origin master` is two separate things, and `origin/master` is one thing.  Three things total.

Two branches:

- `master` is a local branch
- `origin/master` is a remote branch (which is a *local copy* of the branch named "master" on the remote named "origin")

One remote:

- `origin` is a remote

### Example: pull in two steps

Since `origin/master` is a branch, you can merge it.  Here's a pull in two steps:

Step one, fetch `master` from the remote `origin`.  The `master` branch on `origin` will be fetched and the local copy will be named `origin/master`.

```
git fetch origin master
```

Then you merge `origin/master` into `master`.

```
git merge origin/master
```

Then you can push your new changes in `master` back to `origin`:

```
git push origin master
```

### More examples

You can fetch multiple branches by name...

```
git fetch origin master stable oldstable
```

You can merge multiple branches...

```
git merge origin/master hotfix-2275 hotfix-2276 hotfix-2290
```

Comment: So if I do "git clone" once , it wil be created in  both master and origin/master . Right?  In the Clone Graph,  is "1 clone " means  1 clone  action copied to 2 branches?

Comment: The term "git origin master" is used in the context of a remote repository. It is used to deal with the remote repository. The term origin comes from where repository original situated and master stands for the main branch. Let's understand both of these terms in detail. Read [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/git-origin-master)