# Command git push -u origin master not working

Tags: github

When I run the command

```
git push -u origin master
```

it returns the following:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/cistuff/MaxGames.git'
```

When I run the command

```
git push -u origin main
```

it returns the following:

```
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

I tried git push -u origin master and git push -u origin main but I ended up with the errors above. This is my first time doing this so I am very confused.

Comment: Okey, check this post over here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137175/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-origin-master-vs-origin-master Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114676/git-error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-remote) first. You can check your git repository status with the command

> git status

Probably, you have a master branch locally and try to push it to GitHub which they replaced master with a branch called "main". So you might need to use this command in your master branch

> git branch -M main

Here you can use this [git command cheat sheet](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/).