# Git master and dev branches: how to

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

We have 2 branches in a repository `aaa/project`:

- `master` is for production
- `dev` is for developpement

Every developper forks `aaa/project` (`developer-name/project`) and create branches for each feature. When a feature is ok, developer push to his branch, then do a pull request to `aaa/project` on `dev` branch.

Sometimes, `dev` branch (from `aaa/project`) is merged into `master` branch (with 3 or 4 well tested feature).

My problem is:

If something is pushed to `master` branch (critical bug that needs to be in prod ASAP, assuming we have CI), **`dev` branch is not up to date with `master` branch** (on `aaa/project`).

How can we have `dev` branch just like `master` branch just after we merged `dev` into `master` ?

We are using git and bitbucket for hosting (I would prefer a solution directly in bitbucket, because we only clone from our repositories (`developer-name/project`)).

Hope it's clear enough, thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just merge master into dev? Dev *should* always get any changes that master has anyway. Since it sounds like you're merging/pushing to master by some other means, it should be a requirement to update dev with those changes also. For critical bugs you could branch from master, then submit PR back to master *and* dev branches.

Comment: @trnelson Thanks. _"Is there a reason that you can't just merge master into dev?"_ Not really :). I thought it's strange to merge `dev` into `master`, then `master` to `dev`. It's like a circle, but if you says it's acceptable, maybe we will do that.

Comment: Maybe it's related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch (but not sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As trnelson is saying. It is completely normal to merge also from master branch to dev branch.
You could take a look on this excellent presentation about git branching model from Lemi Orhan Ergin!
In our company we have implemented our git workflow according to this presentation.

I'm attaching a screenshot of one slide which, I think, is your case.
[image: Hot fix in production]

This is the link for the whole presentation
[Git Branching Model](http://www.slideshare.net/lemiorhan/git-branching-model)