# Merge parent branch into child branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using bitbucket and sourcetree and I've done this:

I have a develop branch. From this branch I have created a feature branch.

After creating I have fix some errors on develop branch and push it to this branch only.

How can I have these fixes in the feature branch? I think I have to merge develop branch into feature branch but I'm not sure because I'm new in git and I don't want to do something wrong that makes me lose develop branch. but now I want to have these fixes on my feature branch.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want to bring changes from development branch to feature branch. So first switch to feature branch and merge development branch into it. In case you want the commits from develop branch too, use the non fast forward merge `--no-ff` approach. Else do not use `--no-ff`.

```
git checkout feature
git merge --no-ff develop
```

As you are merging develop branch into feature branch, stay assured that develop branch will remain untouched. You may get merge conflicts in feature branch which can be easily solved following the steps on this link: http://softwarecave.org/2014/03/03/git-how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts/

Comment: @Aditya if my feature branches also have some commits or changes in it. And i want these changes also on top after this merge. Will they also be there or it will be removed?

Comment: @Umair seems you should check git rebase as you want your changes on top.

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can merge or preferably rebase develop in your feature.

```
git checkout feature
git rebase develop
```

If you get merge errors you can skip rebase by

```
git rebase --skip
```

or solve the conflicts and continue with (after adding your solution):

```
git rebase --continue
```

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch)