# GIT: Updating a feature branch with changes in master without merge

Tags: git

I'm working on a relatively large GIT repository, which I think follows a reasonably standard setup as follows: Features are developed in new branches, and then get merged back into **master**.

~6 months ago, a feature was partially implemented on a new branch. It turned out that this feature depended on a bunch of other stuff, and so it was put on the back burner until the other stuff was completed.
This leaves the branch in question 18 commits ahead of master, and 93 commits behind, and has a mix of contributors, so we don't want to squash it or loose the history.

How do I get the current changes from **master** onto the feature branch please?

Only thing I can think of at the moment is merging into **master** and then immediately re-branching, but there must be a better method of doing this, as the feature is incomplete....

Comment: Merge `master` into feature or rebase feature onto `master`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git merge master into feature branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch)

Comment: Shameless plug: Here's [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42666870/3345375) to the duplicate question. Basically, you use a new branch: create the branch from master, merge your feature into it, and then use it to work on your feature going forward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Merge `master` into `feature`:

   ```
   $ git checkout feature
   $ git merge master
   ```

   This has the disadvantage that you have to resolve all conflicts at one time.
2. Rebase `feature` onto `master`:

   ```
   $ git checkout feature
   $ git rebase master
   ```

   If there are any conflicts, then you can resolve them manually for each commit in `feature`'s history. Once the conflicts are resolved and added to the index, you do

   ```
   $ git rebase --continue
   ```