# Git merge master branch into some other branch

Tags: git, laravel-5

I have a master branch where my master-app is.

I am expanding the app with a webshop module on top of the master-app.

When i do changes to the master app, i want them to also be in the webshop-app?

When i now do git checkout webshop, the changes i made to master are lost, and i have to copy past them into webshop.

What i do now:

```
git checkout master
git add .
git commit -m "changes made to master application"
git push origin master

git checkout webshop
// copy and paste my changes here
git add .
git commit -m "Changes also made here"
git push origin webshop
```

I tried this:

```
git push origin master webshop
```

But this is only pushing for the commit in the branch i am in atm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git merge master into feature branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
git checkout webshop
git merge master
```

Comment: Does this not merge my webshop into master? Because i don't want that.

Comment: This merges master into webshop. `master => webshop`

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you can (should) only commit to one git branch at a time.

Wanting to commit changes to more than one branch says to me that your'e either misunderstanding GIT's intended workflow, or your'e trying to bend it to a use case that its not designed for.

You should only need/want to commit changes to one branch at a time.  Then if/when you want those changes to be present in another branch, merge it.

```
$ git checkout webshop
... make changes as needed, test, etc
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "some changes are made"
$ git push origin webshop

... then, when your'e ready to merge into your main branch (as said by @vasekhlav)
$ git checkout master
$ git merge origin/webshop
... all changes made in webshop will now be in master, providing there were no conflicts that need to be resolved.
```

After that, you checkout webshop again, and carry on.