# eclipse git how to sychronize local branch with remoter repository package explorer

Tags: eclipse, git

I work with Eclipse and Git.

From command line I did

```
git checkout development
git fetch
git pull
```

After this I  create a new branch

```
git checkout -b <new branch>
```

After this, I went to git package explorer in eclipse. I am in the new branch, but I don't have the changes remote repository

[image]

This is the remote repository

[image]

How can I refresh package explorer with remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of you want to do, but i think you are searching for a rebase. There is a link of a similar question : [Git merge master into feature branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch)

Comment: I want to see in eclipse project explorer in my local branch the remote repository. I dont't see the same in project explorer than remote repository. I want to refresh my new branch

Comment: okey, so you just need to refresh package explorer. well, maybe this can be helpful: https://github.com/samthiriot/genlab/wiki/refresh-the-eclipse-workspace-after-pulling-changes-from-git