# Push changes in current branch into other branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit

I am working on `dev` branch right now. Earlier, I created a `featureX` branch from `dev` branch and since then I've made 15 commits to `dev` branch. Now I want all those 15 commits in `featureX` branch, so that my `featureX` branch can also have all the work I have done in last week in `dev` branch.

I am super confused with `rebase`, `rebase --onto`, etc. commands. Should I be using one of these?

Comment: use 'merge' instead.

Comment: Just so you are aware, Pushing is a verb to describe the action of sending commits (and other stuff) to a specified remote repo. What you’ve described is a merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are three git commands that might be helpful: [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing), [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), and [`merge`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merging).

**rebase**

> The easiest way to integrate the branches...is the merge command. It performs a three-way merge between the two latest branch snapshots...and the most recent common ancestor of the two..., creating a new snapshot (and commit).
>
> However, there is another way: you can take the patch of the change that was introduced...and reapply it on top. In Git, this is called rebasing. With the rebase command, you can take all the changes that were committed on one branch and replay them on a different branch.

In your example, you could do the following:

```
git checkout featureX
git rebase dev
# continue your development on the featureX branch

# if there are conflicts, resolve them, and then continue with
git rebase --skip

# when done with changes, do:
git checkout dev
git merge featureX
```

**cherry-pick**

> Apply the changes introduced by some existing commits.

In your example, you could do the following:

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick ^HEAD dev
```

**merge**

Merge changes from one branch into another.

In your example, you could do the following:

```
git checkout featureX
git merge dev
```

All examples and excerpts are from the documentation:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt-codegitcherry-pickHEADmastercode
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merging

Further reading:

- [Git merge master into feature branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch)

Comment: Thank for the well crafted answer. All these will help me to get the changes to ```featureX``` without effecting ```dev``` branch, right? and then I can continue working on ```dev``` branch, right?

Comment: @Ddp Yes, your changes in `featureX` won’t affect `dev`, unless you merge `featureX` back into `dev`