# How to update my branch in git from contributors in another branch?

Tags: git

I am working on a project on Github.
The project has many branches, but there are only two needed to mention: `develop` and `docs` my job is to push my codes to `docs` branch, and my issue is if someone pushes code to `develop` how can I have those changes in `docs` and resume working without issues.

In pseudocode terms:
guy a: works in `develop`
guy b: checks out `docs` and works on this branch
guy a: is ahead of `docs` by adding more stuff
guy b: wants to synchronize `docs` with develop so he can work on guy a's changes

Comment: Either merge `develop` into `docs` or rebase `docs` onto `develop`. I would opt to rebase the feature onto the main branch but people have their own opinions on this, figure out what works for you.

Comment: That depends on what workflow you want to use. You can either use [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) or [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge master into feature branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case:
guy a: works in develop
guy b: checks out docs and works on this branch
guy a: is ahead of docs by adding more stuff
guy b: wants to synchronize docs with develop so he can work on guy a's changes

On the docs branch:

```
git merge develop
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. I do get this error message `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`

Comment: This is normal situation. You have conflicts on the common code from the branches. Resolve conflicts and commit resolving result. After that you will have a fresh information from the merged branch.

Comment: I can't resolve issues, that's my problem. I don't even know what the conflict is or what it means

Comment: Conflict means what the same code(the same code lines) have been changed in both branches. Conflict resolving means to choose what changes will be applied(from what branch)

Comment: Thanks. I understand this now. Can you please check my newest noob question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756108/git-detached-head-while-checking-out-a-valid-branch

Comment: The best way is to read and practice the git official manual in Branching and Merging part: https://www.git-scm.com/docs After that your question will be more concrete.