# Merge branch by someone else

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Is it possible for someone to merge my branch?

Ie if I make a branch and commit it, can someone else that also owns that repository merge my branch with the main one? And if yes, how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. When you work in a group with each person having access to repo. Anyone can perform . Say if you want to merge a branch(fix) to master.

```
 $ git checkout master
 $ git merge fix
```

Refer this: [Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

Also have a look over this related qsn: [Best (and safest) way to merge a git branch into master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master)