# I have messed up my git - badly

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using git for the 1st time to work with someone in Vietnam. I have another git project in which I have made the same mistakes.

Essentially I have never merged. Anything. Ever.

I have branched  3/4 times. And when the working copy tick (I am using source tree in is the right spot I get the right files in my localhost htdocs and the site works as I expect.

The problem is, the 1st master branch is way way down the other end. and there are are various branches that just seem to stop.

Obviously I need help. I am getting to end of releasing this git to the client future. I want to least look like I know what I was doing with git.pill now I have been a 'one wolf;

Here is an image of the repo. The very bottom is cut off, but they are just the initial commit and a couple of gitignore changes. The real fun starts with the first branch off the master - that I never did merge back again.
[image]

The site ATM is working how is should. So I assume I have done something right, I just feel like its all over the place? I am sure I am supposed to merge branches back into the master if they are right and delete them if the don't work out - right?

Answer (score 1):

If the site is working as it should at the moment, and your changes are on a different branch.  Make sure you have committed everything you want to that branch, then merge the branch back into master.

Here is how you would merge your branch into master : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602109/2657859