# How do I merge a branch into a master in github?

Tags: git-merge

I created a repo and github, and pushed my files to it. Then had a colleague create a branch and make changes. I want to merge the branch to master.

What steps do I take?

Comment: Have you tried `git merge --help` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best (and safest) way to merge a git branch into master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master)

Comment: I had a similar question, and I found this page useful: http://www.deferredprocrastination.co.uk/blog/2012/git-un-merge/

Answer (score 73):

Please do following set of commands in order to merge with the `master`,
Assuming that you are in branch `testBranch` and you want to merge the changes with the `master`,

First checkout to `master` branch,

```
git checkout master
```

Now pull the latest changes in `master`,

```
git pull origin master
```

Merge with the `testBranch`

```
git merge testBranch
```

Push the changes to `master`

```
git push origin master
```

That's it, you are done.

Comment: Its recommended practice to delete the feature branch (testBranch) after merging the code to master. @Actung, you can add this to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could also just create a pull request.

If there are no merge conflicts its easier.

If there are merge conflicts:

`git fetch origin`
`git checkout {branch}`
`git merge master`

Afterwards you have the merge conflict on your branch and you can resolve it.

`git add .`
`git commit -m "{commit message}"`
`git push`

And you have resolved the merge conflict and can merge the pull request onto the master.

Hint: With squash and merge the whole branch is committed as one commit onto master.