# How do I update my master branch?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have two branches, my master branch and my dev branch. I test out changes to my code through my dev branch (leaving my master branch with an older version) because I don't want new code that could mess things up in my master branch. I have finished testing in my dev branch and have concluded that it is stable enough for the master branch, so my question is how do I update my master branch with my dev branch (which has the new -but stable- code).

Comment: Have a look at these: [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), [`git cherrypick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

Comment: Hi aaronth07, I can see that you maybe new here, I would reccomend completing the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , To help improve the question quality!

Comment: I ended up solving my issue by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503686/how-do-i-merge-a-branch-into-a-master-in-github), it is unfortunate that there is no way to use Github for Desktop to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`git merge master` will [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) the changes from your current development branch onto your master branch.

Comment: I tried but it's saying it's already up to date (but I know it isn't since I just compared the two).

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple question, I recommend some reading, a Git GUI can turn the things easier (like Smartgit).

For now: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

For the future: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics