# How to merge single files with git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

So my partner and I are complete Git beginners and are having a hard time just following the terminology let alone making any sense out of the docs and online guides.

**Here's the situation:**

We have a git repo with a bunch of files. We both started with the latest master copy. My partner then made a bunch of changes on a new branch, whereas I made all my changes on my master branch.

Right now **we want to combine our changes.** We both worked on separate files, so really we only need to 'pull' (not sure of the terminology) each other's single file that we worked on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Clarifier**

As an example, let's say there are 5 files: A, B, C, D, and E

We both pulled all the files. Partner worked on A in a separate branch. I worked on B on my master branch. Now I want to give him my B changes and to get his A changes. Thanks again

Comment: have you tried git merge? Read this for reference https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: Take some time and do some tutorials. All the specific answers to specific questions in the world will not really help you. You need to just invest some time to learn properly yourself first.

Comment: @Mort generally, you're right. but sometimes you just need a good solid example to make things click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best (and safest) way to merge a git branch into master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to apply git merge.

Before that,

1) Commit and push all the changes of the `branch` to the remote. Lets say if your branch name is `partner` and assuming you are working on mac, these are the below terminal commands to commit your parner's stuff.

```
git commit -m "Changed something and added something"
git push origin partner
```

Remote is upto date with your `partner` branch changes.

2) On the `master` branch, apply a merge

```
git fetch origin 
git merge origin/partner
```

This means you are merging the partner remote branch to the local master branch.

3) Changes are merged into the local master branch. Now push all the changes to remote master (some times you need to do a commit if there any local changes)

```
git push origin master
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers,
Sha

Comment: cheers. Also look at `git status` command to check the local changes

Comment: wait just tried this, and i got `merge: partner - not something we can merge`

Comment: whats the branch name you want to merge?

Comment: `navbar` - i was just saying `partner` to conform with your example, but i did do `git merge navbar`

Comment: does it matter that i didn't do a pull/fetch/checkout?

Comment: Can you try `git branch -a` and  tell me what you see? This is to see all the local and remote branches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112094/discussion-between-jona-and-sha).

Comment: hmm.. I think your branch `navbar` is not in the remote. Have you pushed the branch `navbar` to remote?