# How to squash commits in Git?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-squash

I am trying to squash my commits and merge my branch to master as one single commit. This is what I'm trying. I switch to master branch and then i do

```
git merge --squash <branch_name>
```

And I get

```
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
```

After that I commit. But however this is what I get

```
$ git commit -m "Resolved"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

For some reason the changes are not reflected and I get the message nothing to commit. I've gone through many posts and questions on stack but nothing of help until now.

Comment: You said *I switch to master branch and then [run `git merge --squash <branch_name>`]* but then you show your `git commit` failure output status as `On branch sample`. That's not `master`. Something does not match up. If you were doing what you are telling us that you are doing, it would say `On branch master`.

Comment: @torek it's a typo in the question. I've corrected it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to squash commits go to HEAD(last) commit and just:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2 && git commit
```

After enter this command you will be asked to write commit message to new commit.
This command will squash your last two commits in one with new commit message you write.

And then merge your branch how it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602109/4093924).

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear to me what commits you are squash-merging and hence why you are getting this result.  You can clear up the first question to yourself (it won't really help *me* much since I don't have the commits) with:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --boundary master...<branch-name>
```

(note the three dots here).  This will show what commits you have now on `master`, and what commits you will be bringing in from `<branch-name>` via the merge base commit(s) of these two branches.

In any case, though, I can make a good guess, because the way `git merge` works is to compare this merge base to the two branch tips.  Here's an example graph fragment from before doing a merge (at this point, it does not matter whether this is a regular merge or a squash merge):

```
...--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       E--F--G   <-- feature
```

Each single uppercase letter represents a commit (whose real ID is a Git hash ID like `a9f3c72` or whatever).  The *merge base* commit here is commit `B`: it's where the chain of commits, starting from both `master` and `feature` at the same time and working backwards (leftwards in this graph), first comes together.  Commit `B`, in other words, is the latest commit that is on *both* branch `master` *and* branch `feature`.  This is what makes it the merge base commit.

Git will now, in effect, run:

```
git diff B D   # see what "we" did on branch master
git diff B G   # see what "they" did on branch feature
```

Git must then *combine* these changes: if we changed `README` to add a line at the end, Git should take this extra line added to the end.  If they changed `foo.py` in some way (added one line and deleted another, perhaps), Git should take their change to `foo.py`.  If we both did *exactly the same things*, though, Git should take just *one copy* of that change.  For instance, if we made the *same* change to `foo.py` on `master`, we don't need their change after all: it's covered by *our* change.

Let's say that we changed `README` and both we and they fixed the *same* thing in `foo.py`, but they also changed `doc.txt` and `main.py`.  So our final set of changes is to keep our added line in `README`, keep our `foo.py` change, and pick up the `doc.txt` and `main.py` changes.  The effect is that Git applies all of these to the contents of the merge base commit `B`.  **This gives us the contents for a new commit `H`.**  (Pay some attention to what's in `H` as it may come back to haunt us.)  Git updates the index (where the next commit to make goes) and work-tree (where we can see what will be or was committed) to this new content, ready for committing.

Now regular vs squash merge suddenly matters, because if Git is to make a *regular* merge commit, it will do this:

```
...--B--C--D---H   <-- master (HEAD)
      \       /
       E--F--G   <-- feature
```

This new *merge commit* `H`, which combines all the work done in commits `C-D` with all the work done in commits `E-F-G`, will point back to *both* commit `D`, the previous tip of `master`, and to commit `G`, the previous and still current tip of `feature`.

If Git is to make a *squash* commit, however—well, it stops after saying:

```
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
$
```

It makes *us* make the commit.  Once we make this commit, we get the new commit `H`, but this time it *does not* point back to *both* `D` *and* `G`.  This time, the new commit `H` points back *only* to `D`:

```
...--B--C--D---H   <-- master (HEAD)
      \
       E--F--G   <-- feature
```

Let's say this all works the way it should, and we *do* in fact make commit `H`.  This gives rise to the case I think is the most likely.

#### The likely case

Let's see what happens now if we run `git merge --squash feature` *again*.

Git starts out the same as before, by finding the merge base: the point where branches `master` and `feature` join.  That's commit `B`, again.

Now Git diffs the two branch tips.  This time, the tip of `master` is `H`, so the two diffs are:

```
git diff B H
git diff B G
```

Git now goes to *combine* these changes.  This time, we changed `README`, `foo.py`, `doc.txt`, and `main.py`.  (Remember, these are the changes we said we got by combining everything.)  Meanwhile they (in `feature`) changed `foo.py` the same way we did, changed `doc.txt` the same way we did, and changed `main.py` the same way we did.

Git therefore takes all of our changes, and none of theirs.  The result *matches commit `H` exactly*.  Git now stops with the same message as before.

This time, when we run:

```
git commit
```

to finish things, Git compares our index (what we have staged for commit) to our `HEAD` commit and finds that these are exactly, totally, 100% identical.  *We already have all the work from `feature`.*  Git says "nothing to commit" and also "working tree clean" as there is nothing to commit and the work-tree matches the index.

#### The less-likely possibility

The other way we could get the same effect here, without making a squash commit `H` first, is if the commit series `E-F-G` "undoes itself" enough that it doesn't matter.  For instance, suppose `F` is the matching change to `foo.py` (it's a copy of commit `C`, perhaps), but commit `G` is a revert of commit `E`.  Now instead of touching `doc.txt` and `main.py`, the sum of the changes from `B` to `G` *is* included in our original `B`-to-`D` changes.  The `git merge --squash` has commits to merge, but again there's no effect on the final *source tree*.  Our index and work-tree will match commit `G` and `git commit` won't make new commit `H` at all.

In terms of "commit differences" this is the same scenario as before: whatever change, if any, gets introduced on the other branch, we already have.  But this time we didn't get it by squash-merging: we just already have it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
> Squash commit -- not updating HEAD

This message probably comes when Your branch is already merged and your again merging it .
For eg. X is main branch ,X1 is child branch ,you did commit to X1 branch and merged it to X branch .From this state
Now if you merge X branch into X1 branch again you will get above message .
as state of two branches are equal in terms of changes.