# How to merge branch to master?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I do have a local branch with some changes, and I want to merge it to remote master. When I run: **`git merge master`** I get:

> Already up-to-date

but I still can see that the master doesn't contain the new changes.

I checked the following issue [Git merge reports “Already up-to-date” though there is a difference Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-reports-already-up-to-date-though-there-is-a-difference), but it seems in one hand to be outdated, and on the other hand, none of the hints there were helpful.

Any idea or hint?

Comment: `git pull origin master` on your branch

Comment: `git merge master` merges _from_ master _to_ the currently checked out branch.

Comment: Yes, I did all these commands.

Comment: Do you want to reflect your branch changes on master or vice versa? If you want to have the changes on master you should rather checkout master and run a `git merge <yourbranchname>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best (and safest) way to merge a Git branch into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/what-is-the-best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you want to merge your branch to master on remote, follow the below steps:

1. push your branch say 'br-1' to remote using `git push origin br-1`.
2. switch to master branch on your local repository using `git checkout master`.
3. update local master with remote master using `git pull origin master`.
4. merge br-1 into local master using `git merge br-1`. This may give you conflicts which need to be resolved and changes committed before moving further.
5. Once merge of br-1 to master on local is committed, push local master to remote master using `git push origin master`.

Comment: TL;DR `git checkout master; git merge yourbranch` (the other steps are unrelated to branch merging, and not everyone may have a remote set (I often work in git locally just for a personal project))

Comment: oops... by using git checkout master, all the changes are gone, so follow this, when you checkout to master branch, then pull code from staging branch and push to master branch.

Comment: Why would you push branch to remote? I think you should remove branch after merging to not get confused .

Answer (score 13):

To merge branch with master,there are two ways you can proceed

- By Git commands
- By Github Dashboard

#### Git Commands

Here also you can go with two different commands,first is

- checkout to your master branch using `git checkout master`
- pull your latest code from the branch you want to merge,use `git pull --rebase origin branch_name`. It may give you some conflicts which you can
  resolve  by using `git status`,after resolving you can check if any
  conflict is more there or not by using `git rebase --continue`.

#### Second way

- To master you can cherrypick the commits from the branch you want to
  merge `git cherry-pick <commit id>`.If you are getting conflict use
  `git cherry-pick --continue`.

Actually this is the more suggested way you can proceed.

#### Merge branch using GitHub Dashboard

This is most easiest way to merge. Create new pull request, select the branch you want to merge and resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Great explanation... just as an info. I'am dealing with gitLab in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Merging into master Or another branch:

```sh
git merge master / or yourBranchName
```

After merging it, check if there is a conflict or not.
If there is NO CONFLICT then:

```
git push
```

If there is a conflict then fix your file(s), then:

```
git add yourFile(s)
git commit -m 'merging my branch'
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it works :

If you want to merge your branch to master on remote, follow the below steps:

push your branch say 'br-1' to remote using git push origin br-1.
switch to master branch on your local repository using git checkout master.
update local master with remote master using git pull origin master.
merge br-1 into local master using git merge br-1. This may give you conflicts which need to be resolved and changes committed before moving further.
Once merge of br-1 to master on local is committed, push local master to remote master using git push origin master.