# What are the git commands to join and replace an x ​branch to the master branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

What git command is used to replace, and what git command do you use to join an x ​​branch to the master branch?

Comment: Are you asking for [git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/what-is-the-best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master)?

Comment: Yes, but there are variants of these and since I'm new, I want to be sure and I don't want to throw the project away. I wanted you to help me here to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

From the command line, use `git merge`, or maybe `git merge --no-ff`.  There is a lot to know before you start, though.

#### Long

If you think about Git in terms of *branches*, you're probably on the wrong path.  Git is not really about branches.  Sometimes I like to shock people a bit by saying Git doesn't have branches,<sup>1</sup> and if by *branch* you mean things like a Mercurial or Subversion branch, or branches from virtually any other version control system that you know well, that's actually true, because the branches Git has are really weird, compared to other version control systems.

So what, then, is Git about?  What does it store?  The answer is: Git stores, and is all about, *commits*.  The commit is the basic unit of Git storage.<sup>2</sup>  Of course, commits do store files, so that's how you *get* files.  But the commit is the central figure in Git.  You should think of Git in terms of commits.  Branches—or rather, one kind of the thing that people mean when they say *branch*—are formed *by* commits.  Branch *names*, which are another thing that people mean when they say *branch*, just let you *find* commits.

To make sense of all of this, it helps a lot to draw some pictures.

---

<sup>1</sup>The point of this is to get their attention.  I'm not sure this is actually a good strategy.

<sup>2</sup>This is by analogy a bit like atoms being the basic unit of physical existence of "everyday stuff".  You can break atoms down into component parts—electrons, protons, neutrons—but by themselves, they don't provide proper existence.  You have to join them up into atoms before you have, say, iron (nucleus of 26 protons, plus neutrons and electrons as needed) or copper (29 protons) or oxygen (8 protons).  (Then you have to join the atoms into molecules, too, so don't push on this analogy too hard. )

---

#### Drawing pictures of commits

Before we can draw a decent picture of a commit, we need to know a few things:

- What's the *name* of a commit?
- What's *inside* the commit?

The name of any commit is its hash ID.  This hash ID, which is a big ugly string of letters and digits like `083378cc35c4dbcc607e4cdd24a5fca440163d17`,<sup>3</sup> is found by creating the commit.  Once it's assigned to *that* commit—whatever commit it is that you, or someone, have created—that hash ID now means *that* commit, and *only* that commit.  No other commit can have that ID!<sup>4</sup>  Moreover, *all* Git software everywhere will agree that *your* commit, with that hash ID, gets *that* hash ID.

The bad thing about these hash IDs is that they are big and ugly and humans just can't deal with them (other than by things like cut-and-paste anyway: if Git shows you a hash ID, you can grab it with your mouse, and paste it into a second Git command).  So we don't, and we usually don't *have* to.  But they are the true names of commits.

Meanwhile, what's *inside* a commit comes in two parts.  One part is a *snapshot:* a full copy of every one of your files.  The other part is *metadata*, which is information *about* the commit.  The metadata include the name of the person who made it: you, or whoever, from your `user.name` setting.  They include the email address of this person, from your `user.email` setting.  They include a date-and-time-stamp of *when* you, or whoever, made the commit.  They include a commit log message explaining to future-you and other people *why* you made this commit.  Most important for Git itself, though, the metadata include the raw hash ID(s) of the commit's *parent* commit(s).  The parent of a commit is the commit that comes *before* this commit.

If we use single uppercase letters to stand in for the hash ID of a commit—commit `A` being the first commit ever, `B` being the second, and so on—we can draw a tiny three-commit repository like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Here `C` is the *last* commit we made.  Inside `C`, Git stores the actual hash ID of earlier commit `B`.  Commit `C` has a full snapshot of all of our files, stored in a compressed and read-only manner.  It has the usual metadata: who made it, when, and why, plus the hash ID of `B`.  So, if we can find commit `C`, we can use it to find `B`.  We say that commit `C` *points to* `B`.

Meanwhile, when we made `B`, we did it from commit `A`, so `B` has a full snapshot of all files—presumably some of them are different from those in `C`—and all the usual metadata.  This time, commit `B` points back to commit `A`, though: `A` is `B`'s parent.  So from `B` we can find `A`.

Commit `A` is a bit special.  It has the same snapshot and log message and so on, but it has *no* parent.  It is [*sui generis*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sui%20generis).  It somehow appeared from nothing, some sort of [spontaneous generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_generation).  Or, more simply, it just has no parent.  Git calls this kind of commit a *root commit* and every nonempty repository has at least one (and usually only one).

But that's it!  We've just successfully drawn a picture of three commits.  As long as we don't care about the *snapshots* in the commits, or their actual hash IDs, this simple:

```
A <-B <-C
```

thing does the trick.  The backwards-pointing arrows are because that's how Git really works: it starts at the *end*, and works backwards, going from commit to commit, until you either get tired of looking and make Git stop, or it reaches a root commit, where it *can't* go back further.

Because it's hard to draw good arrows in any direction (there are some in various fonts but they show up weirdly on some displays) I like to now get lazy and stop drawing the internal arrows:

```
A--B--C
```

Just remember that they point *backwards*.

---

<sup>3</sup>Technically, it's a 160-bit-long string, but we tend to see it as letters and digits.  These hashes are from [Secure Hash Algorithm 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) or SHA-1.  The Git folks plan to move to another algorithm and there will be some sort of transition period where each commit gets *two* names, and there will be much confusion.  But Git will handle this automatically, for the most part.

<sup>4</sup>The possibility of *hash collisions*, which won't happen by accident but which are now being engineered on purpose, is why Git is moving from SHA-1 to another more-secure algorithm.

---

#### Branch names just let us *find* commits

Note that, to use our tiny three-commit repository, we have to start by finding the *last* commit.  We could list out every commit, find all the arrows, and group them together to figure out which one is last.  We could maybe go by dates: list out all commits and find the one with the *latest* timestamp.  There are a lot of things we *could* do here.  But what Git actually *does* do, is use a branch name.

Remember that hash IDs *look* random.  Add to the mix the fact that different commits get made on different computers, and sometimes one computer has the wrong *time* set in it, so that the dates get screwed up.  Add any number of other confounding factors from real life, and there's no obvious way to *find* the *last* commit.  But if we let a *branch name* tell us which commit is *last*, well, that's really easy ... and useful!  Let's draw this in:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

As with the commits that point to earlier commits, we say that the branch name *points to* the last commit.  Not only that, we *define* things this way: *A branch name contains the hash ID of the commit that we will claim is the last commit.*  Now that we've done that, we can have more than one "last" commit, *even if the commits continue*.

That is, let's take our three-commit repository and make a *new* branch name, `develop`, and make `develop` point to existing commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop
```

Now let's add a *new* commit `D`.  We'll write some files into the new commit, put in our name and email address and the current date and time, and set up new commit `D` to point back to existing commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop
       \
        D
```

And, as our final trick of this `git commit` operation, we'll have Git write `D`'s actual hash ID—whatever it may be—into the *name* `develop`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

The name `develop` has stopped pointing to `C` and started pointing to `D`.

Let's make another name `feature` that points not to `D` but to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, feature
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

It's getting confusing here, so let's attach a special name, `HEAD`, to exactly one of these other names to remember which *name* we're using:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, feature (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

Now let's make a new commit `E` in the usual way.  New commit `E` should point back to the *commit* we're using, which is `C`, because `feature` points to `C`.  So we get:

```
        E   <-- feature (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

If we add another new commit `F` without changing branches, we'll get:

```
        E--F   <-- feature (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

Note that every time we make a *new* commit, the *branch name* moves forward.  The special name `HEAD` is still attached to it.  None of the *existing* commits have changed at all.  The *new* commit just points back to what used to be the branch tip, and now the branch tip *is* the new commit.

#### Switching branches

If we now `git checkout master`, we're asking Git to switch from commit `F` *back* to commit `C` again, like this:

```
        E--F   <-- feature
       /
A--B--C   <-- master (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

Note that none of the *commits* changed, and none of the branch *names* moved this time, but `HEAD` is now attached to `master`, and so commit `C` is the current one.  That's what we have out, and we'll see the files *from* `C` in our work-area.

Note, too, that the files inside the commits, like the commits themselves, are frozen for all time.  Nothing and no one can change any of those.  They're in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and frozen format.<sup>5</sup>  Because they *are* read-only, the fact that every commit stores a full copy of every file is cheap: the copies of files in various commits match the copies in other commits, and since commit contents are frozen, Git can just *re-use* the earlier copies.  We only ever add *new* commits, and the new commits re-use existing frozen files automatically.  They only store *new* versions of files as copies.<sup>6</sup>

In order to *work with* our files, though, Git copies them out.  The files you work with, when you work with Git, are in what Git calls your *work-tree* or *working tree* or any number of similar names.  (Git used to use the phrase *working directory* as well, but this is easy to confuse with what the `pwd` command, or *print working directory*, prints.  So *work-tree* is a better name.)

Now you know what `git checkout` does—or at least, part of what it does.  The `git checkout` command actually can do a whole lot of *different* things, probably too many, so in Git 2.23 the Git folks added a new command, `git switch`.  Switching to a branch means *attach HEAD to it, and get files out so I can see and use them.*  The files themselves come from the *tip commit* of that branch, which is the commit whose hash ID is stored *in* the branch (or more precisely, the branch name).

---

<sup>5</sup>I like to call them *freeze-dried*.

<sup>6</sup>Eventually, even those get compressed further, when Git *packs* its internal *objects*.  This is all invisible to normal use: you don't look at Git objects directly, you just `git checkout` a commit and Git defrosts and rehydrates the files from it, into a usable form.

---

#### Which commits are in which branches?

This is where Git's true weirdness with branches shows up.  In most other version control systems, if you make a commit *on* some branch, it *stays* on that branch.  That is, if you have a diagram like this:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

you can easily and correctly say that `feature1` holds commits `I` and `J`, and `feature2` holds commits `K` and `L`.  In some not-Git VCS, that would be true *forever*.  In Git, it's often *not* true.  Moreover, what about the commits leading up to and including commit `H`?  Commit `H` is the tip of `master`—it's the *last* commit on that branch, at the moment—but in Git, commit `H` is on *all three* branches now.

That is, by starting at the last commit of `feature1`, which is `J`, we can work backwards: `J`, then `I`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.  So branch `feature1` *contains* all these commits, with its *tip* being `J`.

Similarly, by starting at the tip of `feature2`, which is `L`, we can work backwards: `L`, then `K`, then `H`—but not `I` or `J`—then `G`, and so on.  So branch `feature2` contains all these commits; the only ones it doesn't contain are the two that are exclusive to `feature1`.

#### Merging

Git's *merge* is perhaps where Git gets its main power.  Commits are the [*raison d'être*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raison_d%27%C3%AAtre) for Git's existence, but `git merge` is probably one of the reasons *you're* using Git.<sup>7</sup>

When we *run* `git merge`, we generally do it like this, at least from the command line:

```
git checkout somebranch      # or now, git switch somebranch
git merge otherbranch
```

It seems like we're merging *branches*.  But no!  As with so many other things in Git, what seem like branch operations are really based on *commits*.  Let's start with this drawing again, but leave the name `master` out of it.  We'll pick one feature to attach our HEAD to, and merge the other:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

This works by *commits*.  You ran `git merge feature2`, so Git finds commit `L`.  You're *on* `feature1`, so Git finds the current commit using `HEAD`: that's `J`.  So Git is supposed to merge `J` and `L`.  These are the two *tip* commits we'd like merged.

Git now uses the *commit graph*—the thing we've been drawing all along here—to go from `J` back to `I` and back to `H`, and from `L` to `K` to `H`.  Having gone backwards along both branches, the first commit that's *on* both branches is clearly `H`.  Not only that, but that's also clearly the *best* common commit.

The *best common commit*, which Git finds automatically, is the *merge base* for any `git merge` operation.  Git now needs to figure out, and merge, two things:

- What did *we* change?  That is, what's the difference between the snapshot in `H`, and the one in `J`?
- What did *they* change?  That is, what's the difference between the snapshot in `H`, and the one in `L`?

To find these, Git runs, in effect, two `git diff` commands.  A `git diff` extracts the snapshots and compares them.  When files match, `git diff` says nothing about them.  When they differ, `git diff` compares the files, line-by-line, and figures out which *lines* match and which are different, and tells us about the differences.

So, given:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>
```

Git will find out what *we* changed, going from the snapshot in `H` to that in `J`.  Then, doing a second `git diff`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>
```

Git will find out what *they* changed.

The merge process, or what I like to call *merge as a verb*, is the process of getting these diffs and combining them.  We—or rather, Git—now apply the *combined* changes to the snapshot from the *merge base*.  That is, after combining all of our changes with all of their changes, Git applies these to the snapshot in `H`.  That *keeps* our changes—the new snapshot will match our `J`, to that extent—but *adds* their changes too: the new snapshot will match our `J`, but with their changes *added*.

Once all this combining is done, so that the merge-as-a-verb process itself is complete, Git will make a *merge commit*.  A merge commit is just like any other commit, except that it records *both tip commits* as its *two* parents.  In other words, this new commit `M` will record both `J`, our commit, and `L`, their commit, as its two parents:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

Like every other commit, `M` has a snapshot.  It's the one made from combining our changes and their changes, and applying that to the merge base.  Like every other commit, `M` has a log message.  Git will generate a not-very-good one, consisting of the phrase *merge branch Y into X* or *merge branch Y* or something along these lines.<sup>8</sup>  The *only* thing that is really special about this merge is that it has *two* parents.<sup>9</sup>

---

<sup>7</sup>Well, that and the ubiquity of sites like GitHub, probably.  But the existence of these sites is enabled by Git's model of distributed committing and the way Git does merging.  Mercurial does all this too, in a way that is easier for most people to use, but with Bitbucket moving from mainly-Hg to mainly-Git, Git seems to have won the VCS war, at least for now.

<sup>8</sup>It is not a bad idea to put in a better one.  People traditionally don't, though.  Git suppresses the `into X` part if `X` is the literal string `master`.  The `git pull` command adds in a URL for for the `merge branch Y` part.  The URL may become invalid over time, and/or the branch names may change over time, which is why this message isn't very good.

<sup>9</sup>Technically, a merge commit is any commit with two *or more* parents.  Git has support for what it calls an *octopus merge*, which is one with more than two parents.  This doesn't do anything you can't do with normal two-parent merges, though, so even though, e.g., Mercurial doesn't have octopus merges, Mercurial can achieve everything Git can.  But this gives rise to the classification scheme for commits: a *root commit* is one with *no* parent, a regular commit is one with one parent, and a *merge commit* is one with two or more parents.  Aside from the number of parents—and the resulting graph—these commits are all the same, really: they all just store metadata and a snapshot.

---

#### Deleting a branch name after a merge

Here is the after-merge picture again:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

Note that the *branch name*, `feature1`, to which `HEAD` is attached, moved in the usual way, to point to new commit `M`.  But since `M` points back to *both* `J` *and* `L`, we can use it to find commit `L`.  We can then use commit `L` to find commit `K`.  We no longer need the *name* `feature2` to find commit `L`.  So we can just delete it:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

The branch name `feature2` is now just *gone*.  The commits that were on `feature2` are also on `feature1`; now they're *only* on `feature1`.  **The set of branch names that find some commit changes dynamically over time.**  So the branch names that *contain* a commit, such as `K` or `L`, may change!

This is why you should think about Git repositories in terms of their *commits*.  The *branch names* don't really mean much.<sup>10</sup>

---

<sup>10</sup>Well, branch names can mean as much as you want them to.  [Glory!](https://sabian.org/looking_glass6.php)  But as with Humpty Dumpty, you might confuse your audience if you force words to mean what *you* want, and *they* don't know that.

---

#### Not all `git merge` commands merge

There's a trick in the graph above.  We started with this:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

but what if we start with this instead:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

and run `git merge feature2`?  Now we're asking Git to merge `feature2` into `master`, i.e., commit `L` into commit `H`.  So let's start with both branch tips and work backwards, to find the first common commit.

From `H`, let's not move at all yet.  From `L`, let's step back once to `K`, then once more to `H`.  Aha!  We've found the shared commit, the *best* one reachable from both branches.

If we do a real merge now, we'll compare the snapshot in `H`, the merge base, to the snapshot in `H`, the branch tip of `master`, to see what *we* changed.  Then we'll compare the snapshot in `H`, the merge base, to the snapshot in `L`, to see what *they* changed.

What will comparing `H` to itself do?  Try it out.  Pick a commit in any Git repository, use `git log` to get its hash ID, and run `git diff <hash> <hash>`.  What happens?

The answer, of course, is that the diff is *empty*.  No files are changed.  There's nothing to combine!  That's absolutely guaranteed, because the merge base *is* the branch tip.

So, in this case, `git merge` takes a short-cut unless you tell it not to.  You can run `git merge --no-ff` to *force* a real merge, which gives you this:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- feature2
```

That is, Git makes a new merge commit as usual, with the two parents being the tip commits, `H` and `L`.  The current branch name advances to point to the new commit, as usual.

If you *don't* force it, though, Git does what Git calls a *fast-forward merge*, which produces this:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- master (HEAD), feature2
```

That is, Git *doesn't* make a new commit `M`.  It just moves the name `master` forward—in the opposite direction of the internal backwards-pointing arrows—to land at commit `L`.  Now the two branch names, `master` and `feature2`, both identify existing commit `L`.

Git will do a fast-forward, instead of an actual merge, when the merge base of the two branch tips *is* the current `HEAD` commit.  You can also find situations in which Git says that there is nothing to merge:

```
...--o--o   <-- branch1
         \
          o--o   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

Running `git merge branch1` produces a complaint, and does nothing, because the commit that `branch1` identifies is already contained within in `branch2`.

#### Combining does not always go well

When you use `git merge`, and it does a true merge—finds a merge base and runs two `git diff`s and so on–Git will *combine* these change-sets.  Usually, Git can do this on its own, because your changes and their changes don't overlap.  But sometimes these changes *do* overlap, or at least touch each other ([abut](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abut)).  In this case, Git will throw its metaphorical hands in the air and say: *This is too hard!  I give up!  Help me Spock!*

In general, what you do in this case is *finish the merge:* figure out what the *correct* combination of these changes is.  This article is too long to go into all the details, but Git leaves you with a mess, in the index and in your work-tree, and you have to clean it up.  Then you run `git merge --continue` or `git commit`, to finish the merge process and make the final merge commit.

Sometimes, Git *thinks* all went well, but the resulting merge is not actually correct.  In this case it is up to you to decide how to handle it.  You can just make a followup commit that fixes whatever went wrong, or you can "undo" the merge or do other tricky things.<sup>11</sup>  No method is completely satisfactory, but the simplest—just add a followup commit, with a good log message explaining exactly what happened—is, I think, usually the best approach.

**Usually, everything just works ... but it's wise to test stuff.**  If you have a CI system, that will presumably test the result.

---

<sup>11</sup>You can, for instance, use `git commit --amend` to make an [*evil merge*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452).  Note that `--amend` doesn't actually change any *existing* commit—it literally can't do that—but what it does do works fine for regular commits, but can produce these so-called evil merges, when used on merge commits.

Answer (score 1):

The `git merge` command is the answer.

I try to explain you the command.

Starting from the definition of `git merge` : ***The "merge" command is used to integrate changes from another branch.***

Pay attention: *The target of this integration (i.e. the branch that receives changes) is always the currently checked out HEAD branch.While Git can perform most integrations automatically, some changes will result in conflicts that have to be solved by the user.*

Now some useful options:

```
--no-ff
```

*Creates a merge commit even when a fast-forward would be possible.*

```
--squash
```

*Combines all integrated changes into a single commit, instead of preserving them as individual commits.*

```
--abort
```

*When a conflict occurs, this option can be used to abort the merge and restore the project's state as it was before starting the merge.*

Now in your case(if I understand correctly) you want to merge x branch to the master. 
So the sequence can be this :

```
git checkout master
```

To switch to the master branch.
Now if you work on remote repository is good practice to do :

```
git pull
```

To update local copy of your repository.
Then you can do the merge safely:

```
git merge xBranch
```

--squash option is a good practice when merging, but is ok also without.
Now you maybe need to resolve some conflicts. Then you can do a simple commit with `git add filename` and `git commit` commands, and at the end, if your repository is remote you can do `git push`.