# Git: Merge a branch

Tags: git

I have two branch:

- develop
- myBranch

I'm working on myBranch and some other makes a push on develop.

So now I should merge my branch "myBranch" into develop.

So I'll checkout on develop, i'll make a pull and then can I merge "myBranch" ?

```
git checkout develop
git pull 
git merge myBranch
```

it is rigth in your opinion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best (and safest) way to merge a Git branch into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601931/what-is-the-best-and-safest-way-to-merge-a-git-branch-into-master)

Comment: could you add the commands you were thinking of using? I do think this is a duplicate

Comment: I have wrote the command that I would do, but i'll edit

Comment: Yes it looks fine. Also, you will probably want to pull develop into your branch first, you can do that in your branch by using `git pull origin develop`

Comment: Unless you are done with `myBranch`, you should merge `devel` into `myBranch`, or rebase `myBranch` on top of `level`.

Comment: If you weren't ready to merge `myBranch` into `devel` before the push to `devel`, the push hasn't changed that.

Comment: @chepner the branch that should be always updated is develop, you suggest anyway to do in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first merge `devel` into `myBranch` until you are ready to incorporate your changes into `devel`. Another developer pushing to `devel` does not require you to do the same immediately.

```
# Get any new changes from the remote
git fetch

# You don't necessarily need to update your copy of devel yet;
# just merge the new commits from devel into myBranch
git merge origin/devel

# continue working on myBranch

# Time to merge your changes to devel. 
git checkout devel
git pull
git merge myBranch
```

Merging `devel` into `myBranch` while you develop lets you resolve any merge conflicts as they come along, rather than having to resolve all of them at once when you finally merge `myBranch` into `devel`. If you merge often, you should minimize, if not eliminate, the merge conflicts during `git merge myBranch`.

Comment: So in my branch: "myBrancH"  i should merge orgin/develop before? 
It doesn't overwrite the changes I made right?

Comment: Overwrite, no, but there may be merge conflicts to resolve where both `devel` and `myBranch` have made similar but different changes.

Comment: But you still need to *test* your code following the merge. A merge may not overwrite your changes, but it can make things you assumed no longer be true.

Comment: ok , ty so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the `git pull`, that would be pulling the changes from remote.
If you want to just merge, then it's:

```
git checkout <branch to merge into>
git merge <feature branch>
```

Comment: I'm doing git pull because the develop branch have new commits done (not from me)

Comment: Fair enough. I thought maybe you thought that was part of the processes you need to follow when merging.