# Squash to only one "proper" commit for github pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have a repo on github which someone else (Bob, for the sake of argument) has issued a pull request for. His code's not perfect, so we go through a few rounds of markups. As I understand it, he commits and pushes to his pull-request for each set of marked up changes.

So my repository now looks like this:

```
master: ---o A (Chowlett
           |
           |
pull-req:  o---o---o---o
               B   C   D (all Bob)
```

Commit SHAs and msgs are as follows:

A:

```
123456 Good commit <chowlett>
```

B:

```
777ccc Fix the widget bug <bob>
```

C:

```
888ddd Review markups <bob>
```

D:

```
999eee Further markups <bob>
```

I'm now happy to accept this pull request; but I'd rather the pre-markup versions weren't in my repo. Can I achieve all of the following; and how?

- Merge B, C & D into my repo as a single commit
- Generate the "Merge pull request #99 into ..." commit as well
- Have github automatically close the pull request

Comment: Ask the contributor to rebase the changes into a single commit and merge that one.

Comment: @Stefan - doesn't that go against the "don't rebase a commit that's been pushed remotely" dictum?

Comment: @Chowlett That's a good rule of thumb, but it isn't harmful when the remote branch hasn't been merged and nobody else is using it.

Comment: @JeremiahOrr - Hmm, ok. So, Bob could just `rebase -i 123456`, squash C and D, then `push -f`? And github would update what was in the pull request?

Comment: @Cowlett Yes, that's exactly what would happen. Sometimes the comments in the pull request can get messed up, particularly if you made comments on specific lines in the commit, but otherwise it will be fine.

Comment: @Chowlett Or Bob could push the squashed commits to another branch, open a new pull request and close the first one.

Comment: @Stefan - Ok, thanks. If you or Jeremiah want to make that an answer, I'll happily upvote, and accept one of them.

Comment: @Stefan How would you do "Or Bob could push the squashed commits to another branch" exactly?
I have this problem too: I want to deliver a clean-one-commit pull request, but I don't want to lose my development branch history by squashing it.
It seems every upstream repository owner on github asks contributors  to squash their commit, but that seems backwards to me.

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/anaran/devtools-snippets/network where I tried to create a single commit in `issue35take2` using `git checkout -B issue35take2 master && git merge --no-ff devtools_import_export`.
Nonetheless the pull request to upstream/master contains every single commit from devtools_import_export.

Comment: @stackunderflow please open a new question.

Comment: @Stefan I tried an answer instead.

Answer (score 17):

Note that Bob doesn't have to squash his commits when he is making a GitHub PR.
Since March 2016, you can leave that operation to the maintainer (you) accepting your PR.

See "[Squash your commits](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits)" and its [new documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merge-squashing/)

> This is a new option which lets you force commit squashing on all pull requests merged via the merge button.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/squash-and-merge.png]

Comment: The docs say 1 April. I was not sure if they were joking or not, but it seems to be a sticker :)

Comment: @RobW I confirm, it is not an April fool joke. (https://twitter.com/synhershko/status/716465979828604928)

Comment: I don't understand the point in squashing all work into one large commit which is impossible to review, reused, and reverted.

Comment: @reversiblean it depends on the nature of the commits being squashed: sometime, you have a small patch composed of multitude smaller commits, all trials and errors: it that history is not important, you might want to present your PR as the final result (squashed commit) instead of the noise represented by *all* the commits done to get to that result.

Answer (score 10):

There are two 'squash' functions inbuilt into `git`. There is `git merge --squash` and there's the `squash` action in `git rebase --interactive`. The former doesn't retain any author or date information, just collecting all changes from a series of commits into the local working copy. The latter is annoying because it requires interaction.

The [`git squash` extension](https://github.com/jnothman/git-squash) does what you want. It rebases the current HEAD onto a specified base while automatically squashing the commits in between. It also provides a command-line option to set the message on the final squashed commit in cases where the rebase doesn't create conflicts.

Throwing this together with [`hub`](http://defunkt.io/hub/) and [`ghi`](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi), you might be able to construct a script along these lines:

```
git pull upstream master
hub checkout https://github.com/$user/$repo/pull/$issue
git squash master
rev=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
git checkout master
git merge $rev
git commit --amend "Merged pull request #$issue"
git push upstream master
ghi close $issue $user/$repo
ghi comment $issue "Merged as $rev" $user/$repo
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the --squash option for merge

```
git merge <remote url> <remote branch> --squash
```

This will however not produce a merge commit.  It will instead produce a normal set of working tree changes as if you manually applied all of his changes to your copy.  You would then commit like normal.

The downside will be that your history on master will not show this commit as a merge from his branch.  It will just look like you did the work yourself and not give Bob credit.

Answer (score 3):

### Using git rebase

One idea would be to checkout the branch and squash all commits into one using the iteractive rebase, then force push to update the pull request and merge (though part of this work could be delegated to Bob).

To automatically squash all commits from a branch into the first one and apply this to the pull request, you can use the following commands:

```
$ git checkout pull-req
$ GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='sed -i "2,\$s/^pick/s/g" $1' git rebase -i origin/master
$ git push --force
```

[GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=821881d88d3012a64a52ece9a8c2571ca00c35cd) is a Git environment variable to set a temporary editor for the rebase commit list. We set it to a inline script which replaces the word `pick` by `s` (meaning `squash`) in the beginning of all lines except the first (that's the `2,\$` in the `sed` pattern). The commit list that gets passed to the script is a simple text file. Git then proceeds with the rebase and lets you edit the final commit message.

Also, with a git hook you could then more or less easily edit this final message to suit your needs (say add a visual separator between the squashed commits' messages).

### Using git merge --squash

Squashing is also possible through `git merge --squash`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase) for the difference between the two methods. The script bellow would squash the commits of a branch into a single commit using the merge command. It also creates a backup of the branch (just in case).

```bash
MAINBRANCH="master"    
CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

# update current feature branch with master
git pull origin $MAINBRANCH

# delete existing backup
git branch -D "$CURRENT_BRANCH-backup"

# backup current feature branch and go back
git checkout -b "$CURRENT_BRANCH-backup" && git checkout -

# checkout and update master branch
git checkout $MAINBRANCH && git pull

# create new branch from master
git checkout -b "$CURRENT_BRANCH-squashed"

# set it to track the corresponding feature branch
git branch "$CURRENT_BRANCH-squashed" --set-upstream-to "$CURRENT_BRANCH"

# merge and squash the feature branch into the one created
git merge --squash $CURRENT_BRANCH

# commit the squashed changes
git commit

# force push to the corresponding feature branch
git push -f . HEAD:$CURRENT_BRANCH

# checkout the feature branch
git checkout $CURRENT_BRANCH

# delete the squashed copy
git branch -D "$CURRENT_BRANCH-squashed"
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked out for me.

- My work on `devtools_import_export` stays intact.
- My pull request for `issue35squashed` to upstream/master has only one commit.
- Alas, the merge isn't recorded, but the commit message has all details.

Here is what I actually did (see https://github.com/anaran/devtools-snippets/network)

```
git checkout master
git status # all clean
git checkout -B issue35squashed master
git merge --squash devtools_import_export
git status # looks good
git commit # review and commit via emacs
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --stat --pretty --decorate=full --branches
git push --all -v
```

(My earlier attempt using `git merge --no-ff ...` is in `issue35take2` and a pull request for it contains all the individual commits from `devtools_import_export`. No good.)