# Squash all my commits into one for GitHub pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request, squash

I made a pull request on GitHub. Now the owner of the repository is saying to squash all the commits into one.

When I type `git rebase -i` Notepad opens with the following content:

```
noop

# Rebase 0b13622..0b13622 onto 0b13622
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

I searched on Google but I do not understand how to do this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Squash my last X commits together using Git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5189560/456814).

Comment: You don't have to squash anymore: the owner can do it for you (since March 2016): see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36377439/6309

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Just a simple addition to help someone else looking for this solution. You can pass in the number of previous commits you would like to squash. for example,

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

This will bring up the last 3 commits in the editor.

Comment: Doing `git rebase -i HEAD~2` for me brings up an editor with like 20 lines of commits. And none of them are the last two commits I want. What's going on?

Comment: Probably your previous commit is a merge.

Comment: See also @omerjerk's answer below about editing the last 2 commits from pick to squash

Comment: this isn't useful if you've merged in a branch like master that has more recent updates

Answer (score 50):

ok I figured it out ...
First I had to write `git rebase -i xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` where xxxxxxxxxx is the SHA of the commit upto which I've to squash. Then in Notepad I edited the first as pick and rest of all as squash. Then a new notepad window will come and there in the first line I typed the name of my new commit.
And then I had to do a force push :

```
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to force push or rebase a branch that is already pushed to remote. All other people who had the un-rebased master branch will get an error, and they will be confused.

Comment: what does "up to" mean exactly? Is xxxxxxxxxxx included or not included?

Comment: @luckykrrish How does one squash commits on a public pull request then?

Comment: @luckykrrish That's a perfectly acceptable thing to do on your own PR branch.

Comment: I got conflict. Thank you very much for this. No one mentions about this in no other answer.

Comment: it is better to use `--force-with-lease`

Comment: Usually not a good idea to force push to master. You'd want to squash your commits on your feature branch instead.

Answer (score 40):

[As of April 1, 2016](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits), the repository's manager can squash all the commits in a pull request into a single commit by selecting "Squash and merge" on a pull request.

[image: Squash and merge option]

If you want to manually squash commits in a pull request, refer to [fontno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534397/squash-all-my-commits-into-one-for-github-pull-request/16642628#16642628).

Answer (score 11):

Try `git rebase -i`, and use 'squash' for all the commits you want to squash.

Edit:

`git rebase -i` will show you an interactive editor with the list of commits you are rebasing. The default command before each commit is "pick", so you just need to s/pick/squash/ for all the commits you want to squash, and then all of them will be squash into their last previous commit.

Make sure you are rebasing on a correct branch.

Comment: I didn't get it.. I already said I know nothing of these things.

Comment: `git rebase -i` will show you an interactive editor with the list of commits you are rebasing. The default command before each commit is "pick", so you just need to s/pick/squash/ for all the commits you want to squash.

Comment: `git rebase -i` is followed by a branch name, make sure you have read the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: ok I got it. and squashed all the changes into a new commit . but when clicked on sync then those commits again came.  should i do something else after squashing ?

Comment: when you write "s/pick/squash/", what is the "s" option?

Comment: "s/pick/squash" means "replace pick with squash".

Comment: It's `sed` syntax (Stream EDitor), a very powerful but arcane Linux tool. The `s` command stands for "switch" (or replace), followed by a search string and a replacement string, separated by slashes. Usually followed by "g", which means "global", or "do this replacement not just once but everywhere". So `s/pick/squash/g` means: "replace every instance of `pick` with `squash`".

Comment: This is a very helpful answer! Thanks!

Comment: It's a great discussion but it does not answer the question what one should actually do. `error: invalid line 3: s/pick/squash/g` does not seem to be a successful execution

Comment: This is pathologically wrong with git