# Squash GitHub commit online

Tags: github

I have made my first contribute to a project on GitHub.
I have selected the file to edit, created a pull request, and made my edits.
Then I noticed a mistake, selected the file again, and made my corrections.
I always worked online, no command line.
Now a contributor od the project asked me to squash my two commits.
The question is: how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534397/squash-all-my-commits-into-one-for-github-pull-request

Comment: I doubt that you can. GitHub's online editing facilities are pretty basic, and aren't anything close to a complete Git client. You will probably have to do this offline.

Comment: Ok I will try from the command line. But how can I "move" from the online editor to the command line?

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I "move" from the online editor to the command line?

See [Modifying an active pull request locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/#modifying-an-active-pull-request-locally) in GitHub's documentation:

> 1. In any repository's right sidebar, click **Pull Requests**.
> 2. In the "Pull Requests" list, click the pull request you'd like to merge.
> 3. At the bottom of the pull request, click **command line**. Follow the sequence of steps to bring down the proposed pull request.

Then modify the branch locally.

In this case you'll want to [squash the commits using `git rebase --interactive <commit-before-yours>`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits). Choose to `pick` your first commit and `squash` your second one.

Finally, push it back to the existing PR branch on GitHub. In this case you'll have to use `--force` since you're replacing your old commits with a new one.