# Squash commits on GitHub PR

Tags: git, github, squash

I have made 6 commits on a GitHub branch completely online and I need to squash them into 1 commit. Is there a button for me to do this? I've only made the commits on the GitHub website so is there a way to do this without using the command line?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33962191/946226

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Squash GitHub commit online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962191/squash-github-commit-online)

Answer (score 3):

When merging, instead of just clicking the "Merge pull request" button, click the drop down menu and select "Squash and merge" option (second option down):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! However I am trying to merge into another repository, not my own. Do you have any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can't merge your commits purely with GitHub (I did a brief search on Google, there seems no introduction with it), but you can [squash your commits during merging](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits). In your question says `on a GitHub branch completely online`, it seems that you are holding a second branch on GitHub. Then, while you are merging that branch to master branch, you are able to decide whether merging these 6 commits into 1.

Answer (score 0):

Github itself doesn’t provide this functionality, but it is possible to do so using the Github API, and the service at https://squasher.nomeata.de/ will squash your commits, given the PR URL.