# How to clean-up history commit with no lose changes

Tags: git, github

I'm working in my own fork and doing some changes in too many commits.

Now, i have to merge my fork in the original fork and i want that in the pull request, only show one commit with all changes thah i did i all commits.

It is posible?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is duplicated. I was looking for with no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to squash all commits on branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356810/git-how-to-squash-all-commits-on-branch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squash to only one "proper" commit for github pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396069/squash-to-only-one-proper-commit-for-github-pull-request)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull-request+one+commit

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all commits in pull request and can squash merge the PR. This way you will result only in one commit.
You can refer this to see how to squash merge :
[How to use git merge --squash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash)